# Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate

Tags: plotting, evaluation, faq

This example comes from
[the Mathematica documentation for `Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot&lang=en)
under *Basic Examples*.

Can someone please explain why these are each plotted as a different color in this case:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

But when `Evaluate[]` is removed, all of them are the same color:

```
Plot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

I know it must have to do with the order of things being evaluated, but I'm really not sure why it is working like this - can someone please point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Hmm... I'm almost positive I've seen this question asked here before, but I can't seem to find it...

Comment: Yeah, this is very much an FAQ.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The list structure is not manifest to `Plot` as it has the attribute `HoldAll` (to get a function's attributes, either use `Attributes[func]` or `??func`). Hence `Plot` evaluates the `Table` functions as one unit and it appears as if there is only one function, not four.

`Evaluate` will make the list structure manifest and each function will be plotted with a separate style.

Comment: I apologize if this is naive question, but what does "The list structure is not manifest to Plot" mean?

Comment: It means that Plot isn't seeing the argument as a list. A list is treated as one argument not many arguments as Plot has HoldAll attribute .

Comment: if I use `Evaluate[...]` or `Evaluated->True` it takes forever to plot the functions, as compared without those. Is there any way to still assign different colors without losing the speed?

Answer (score 46):

#### *Mathematica 10* update

It seems that now `Plot` specifically recognizes `Sequence` which invalidates the example given below, but not its premise.  If one uses a *different* head that behaves similarly the behavior is still exhibited:

```
Plot[{1, ## &[2, 3], 4}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

Or:

```
f[x__] := x

Plot[{1, f[2, 3], 4}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

Or:

```
Plot[{1, {2, 3} /. {x__} :> x, 4}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

---

### Analysis

`Plot` builds style lists based on the *apparent* structure of the first argument it is given, before evaluation.  `List` is recognized and elements are styled individually, while generic functions like `Table` are styled as a whole.

You can see this behavior here, where `Sequence` acts as a "generic head":

```
Plot[
  {1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}, {x, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Thick
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

On the other hand sub-lists are recognized and styled:

```
Plot[
  {1, {2, 3}, 4}, {x, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Thick
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can read [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605635/618728) about this and Sasha's excellent answer (starting from EDIT 2).

---

### Recommended form for evaluation

I recommend that you use the option `Evaluated -> True` rather than `Evaluate` as it (still) localizes the plot variable.  See:

- [Normal[Series[ ]] does not give a normal expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7559/normalseries-does-not-give-a-normal-expression/7561#7561)
- [Help on evaluation control?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7828/help-on-evaluation-control/7832#7832)

Comment: Clever trick to use `Sequence[]` to constrain a group to have the same color... :)

Comment: This is not working anymore in V10 :( I liked it, this however, works: [72929](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72929/5478). They not how to handle `Sequence` but `## &[2, 3]` will do! :)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the note; I hadn't yet noticed it.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: To which V10 version does your Mathematica 10 update apply? With MMA V10.1 and  `Plot[{1, ## &[2, 3], 4}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick]'  I get an error (`Identity::argx: Identity called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected`

Comment: @SigisK That was for 10.0.2.  Thanks for letting me know that the new form is broken too.  When I get 10.1 I'll see what I can learn.

Comment: @SigisK What about the other two methods shown in the Update section?

Comment: The other two methods also get the same error.

Comment: @SigisK I am now using 10.1.0 under Windows and all three of the "Mathematica 10 update" methods work without error on my system.  What operating system do you use?

Comment: I am sorry to have misled you, I genuinely thought to have a 10.1 version: I was  confused between `$Version` which returned 10.0 and `$ReleaseNumber` which returned 1 (and I concatenated these 2 to make 10.1) and I forgot to give a feedback . I upgraded now to 10.1 and these errors are gone but others are still present (please look at my latest question to which I gave my own answer since no answer was given after 4 months).

Comment: @SigisK I shall take a careful look at your Q&A later.  (I am only briefly checking in a few times today.)  I am sorry to see what appears to be a good Q&A fall through the cracks.  For what it's worth a few of mine have too despite the presumed name recognition I have here.  Please do not let it discourage you from posting.

Comment: +1 for `Evaluated -> True`. Just solved my problem of long computation due to algebraic simplification of `Plot`'s argument prior to each evaluation.

Comment: @Casimir Happy to help.  Be aware that in recent versions the `Evaluated` does not work with `PlotLegends`; see [(69104)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69104/121)

Answer (score 24):

`Evaluate` *evaluates* your expression that you want to plot. This transforms the expression `Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]` that you give as an argument into a list of several functions. If `Plot` sees several functions, it knows it can use more colors. Without `Evaluate`, `Plot` does not know you have several functions and uses only one color. That comes from the fact that `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll`: it does not evaluate your arguments. Without evaluation the first time it sees, that several numbers are coming out of your function is during the plotting. Then it's too late to color it differently, and you get only a single colored plot.

Answer (score 12):

Just to strengthen the idea that Plot does not evaluate the expression even with simplest operations

```
Plot[0 + {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: It took me 5 minutes to understand what you meant. It would be easier if you mentioned the the curves have the same color because of unevaluated expression

Comment: One can check that (in v 13, at least) `Plot[Evaluate[0 + {Sin[x], Cos[x]}], {x, 0, 2 π}, Filling -> Axis]` works, while `Plot[0 + {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, Filling -> Axis,Evaluate->True]` only half works.