# Plotting Partial Sums of Fourier Series

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis

I'd like to plot some partial sums for a Fourier Series problem, but I am not sure if the output I am getting is correct. I want to be able to plot the partial sums and the function on the same graph. Here is something that I attempted.

```
 s[n_, x_] :=  8/4 + 3/(9 π) Sum[(6 (-1)^k)/(k π) 
                Cos[(k π x)/2] + (16 (-1)^k + 13)/(π k) 
                Sin[(k π x)/2],{k, 0, n}]

 partialsums = Table[s[n, x], {n, 1, 5}];

 f[x_] = Piecewise[{{-x^3-2x,-2 < x < 0},{-1+x,0<= x <= 2}}]

 Plot[Evaluate[partialsums], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]
```

Any ideas about the best method to tackle something like this?

Comment: There's a k in the denominator of the sum (actually, two) and your index for k goes from 0 to n, so the sum is always indeterminate.

Comment: @DavidSkulsky: Should it be `{k,1,n}`. I actually only want to plot a certain amount of partial sums. Does this number go where the `n` is located?

Comment: Once you fix the sum, you should be able to plot what you want by just doing Plot[Append[partialsums,f[x]],{x,-4 Pi, 4 Pi}].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the definition of `s` you're summing from `k==0`. Since the summand has a term `1/k` this gives a divide-by-zero error when calculating the partial sums. The sum should in fact start from `k==1` (the zeroth coefficient is taken care of by the constant term in front of the sum). The first few approximations then look like

```
s[n_, x_] := 
 8/4 + 3/(9 π) Sum[(6 (-1)^k)/(k π) Cos[(k π x)/
        2] + (16 (-1)^k + 13)/(π k) Sin[(k π x)/2], {k, 1, n}]

partialsums = Table[s[n, x], {n, 1, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate[partialsums], {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To compare this with `f` we plot the `s[5,x]` and `f` in the same plot:

```
Plot[{s[5, x], f[x]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which doesn't seem right to me, so I suspect you made a mistake somewhere in calculating the coefficients.

**Calculating coefficients by hand**

We could use `FourierSeries` to calculate the partial sums, but this is very slow, and  doesn't give produce the general equation for the coefficients. Therefore it's better to calculate the coefficients by hand. The $n$-th coefficient can be calculated according to

```
coeff[0] = 1/4 Integrate[f[x], {x, -2, 2}];
coeff[n_] = 1/4 Integrate[f[x] Exp[I Pi n x/2], {x, -2, 2}]
```

> ```
> (1/(2 n^4 π^4))E^(-I n π) (-48 + 48 E^(I n π) - 
>  48 I n π + 28 n^2 π^2 - 6 E^(I n π) n^2 π^2 + 
>  2 E^(2 I n π) n^2 π^2 + 12 I n^3 π^3 - 
>  I E^(I n π) n^3 π^3 - I E^(2 I n π) n^3 π^3)
> ```

Then the partial sums are given by

```
series[m_, x_] := Sum[Exp[-I Pi n x/2] coeff[n], {n, -m, m}]
```

Plotting the first few approximations:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[series[j, x], {j, 0, 5}]], {x, -6, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To see how this compares with the original function `f`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{series[5, x], f[Mod[x, 4, -2]]}], {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which looks a lot better than the before.

**Edit: Real coefficients**

Here, `coeff[n]` are the coefficients for the Fourier series in [exponential form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Exponential_Fourier_series), but these can be easily converted to the coefficients for the $\cos$ and $\sin$ series, `a_n` and `b_n`, by doing something like

```
a[0] = coeff[0];
a[n_] = Simplify[ComplexExpand[coeff[n] + coeff[-n]]];
b[n_] = Simplify[ComplexExpand[I (coeff[n] - coeff[-n])]];
```

Comment: Thanks, This is a very interesting way or technique of doing this. I also like that about how to covert back and forth between the exponential form and the trigonometric forms. That will be very useful. :). Very neat and organized approach.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`FourierCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FourierCoefficient.html) to pre-calculate the Fourier coefficients to arbitrary degree and then use the result very effectively.

There may be some issues with zero-th degree, therefore I excluded this using `Piecewise`. Here's the main code block:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{
    {-x^3 - 2 x, -2 < x < 0},
    {-1 + x, 0 <= x <= 2}},
    0
];
    Module[{x, fp},
    (* Set parameters so that the integration runs
       from -2 to 2 *)
    fp = {0, -Pi/2};
    fc = Piecewise[{
        {FourierCoefficient[f[x], x, 0, FourierParameters -> fp], # == 0},
        {ComplexExpand@FourierCoefficient[f[x], x, #, FourierParameters -> fp], True}
    }] &;
    fc = Evaluate /@ fc;
];
```

The output (`fc`) of this is something very unpleasant to look at; however, there's nothing Fourier-related left there, all the hard math has been done already, and only a bunch of elementary functions remain. `fc` is now a function of one argument that gives you the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of `f` in no time.

```
(* Calculate the first 2001 Fourier coefficients *)
AbsoluteTiming[Table[fc[n], {n, -1000, 1000}]] // First
```

> ```
> 0.777059 seconds
> ```

To convert this back to the function, you have to do the partial sum with your hands, for example here are the second, fourth and eightieth partial sums:

```
myPartialSums = Table[
    (* The Pi/2 compensates for the custom FourierParameters, see
       documentation of FourierSeries/FourierParameters
       under "more info" *)
    Re[Sum[fc[k] Exp[-Pi/2 I k t], {k, -n, n}]],
    {n, {2, 4, 80}}
];
```

> ```
> A very large output has been generated,
> but we're luckily not interested in it
> anyway but would rather plot it
> ```

```
Plot[
    {f[t]} ~Join~ myPartialSums,
    {t, -10, 10},
    PlotRange -> All, 
    Evaluated -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}
]
```

> [image: plot of Fourier series partial sums]

Answer (score 6):

If the summation index goes from 1 to n, as you suggested (?) above, and you make the mod to the Plot function I mentioned

```
s[n_, x_] := 8/4 + 3/(9 π) Sum[(6 (-1)^k)/(k π) Cos[(k π x)/
    2] + (16 (-1)^k + 13)/(π k) Sin[(k π x)/2], {k, 1, n}]

partialsums = Table[s[n, x], {n, 1, 5}];

f[x_] = Piecewise[{{-x^3 - 2 x, -2 < x < 0}, {-1 + x, 0 <= x <= 2}}]

Plot[Evaluate@Tooltip[Append[partialsums, f[x]]], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]
```

Then you get the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Your plot is running into a known issue with mma which I can't seem to find a reference to. Since `Plot` has the `Attribute` `HoldAll`, it is treating `Append[partialsums, f[x]]` as a single function, and hence colors all the lines the same color. To get around this either use `Evaluate@Append[...]` or `Plot[#, ...]& @ Append[...]`.

Comment: Interesting-I was wondering about that! Thanks!

Comment: Thats nice David. I was wondering what was going on with the colors. I was fooling around with it to get something like this and then I seen that rcollyer figured it out. Thank You, that will be a useful option to remember when doing these. Thank You! `:)`

Comment: @nightowl and David, I found the [discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/52) on this.