# Changing the plot variable inside Plot

Tags: plotting, evaluation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference in Plot when using Evaluate vs when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/difference-in-plot-when-using-evaluate-vs-when-not-using-evaluate)

Assume one has vector of functions (e.g., `vec={x,x^2}`).

The command `Plot[vec, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]` allows one to plot curves in different colors.

[image]

Any use of the replacement operator, however, causes all curves to adopt the final listed color. For example, `Plot[vec /. x -> y, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]` gives

[image]

How does one specify different colors for different curves if a replacement (`/.`) is used within the plot command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` (you can check with `Attributes[Plot]`), which makes it not recognize the two separate curves and "sees" it as one. Use `Evaluate` to overcome this.

```
Plot[Evaluate[vec /. x -> y], {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I didn't know about the `HoldAll` attribute. Having now read about it, if I understand correctly, `Hold[x/.x->y]` prevents the substitution from taking place. How does `Plot` manage to plot the curves (incorrect colors aside) over the domain $y\in\left[-2,2\right]$ if the substitution $x\mapsto y
$ never takes place?

Comment: There's probably some `ReleaseHold` called further down...though that's a good question :)

Comment: @user001 `HoldAll` does not prevent the replacement from taking place — you can see this with simply doing `HoldAll[vec /. x -> y]`. However, what it does do is prevent `Plot` from recognizing that there are _two_ functions in that list and makes it see only one. You can learn more from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607141) by Sasha to a related question.