# Plotting different PDFs of a distribution in the same graph

Tags: plotting

How would I plot the PDF (probability density function) of `WeibullDistribution[1/5, 50]`, `WeibullDistribution[1/4, 40]`, `WeibullDistribution[1/3, 30]` and `WeibullDistribution[1/2, 20]` in the same graph?

Comment: There are good examples how to do this in the documentation of the {WeibullDistribution}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple way. The `Evaluate` is needed to ensure the line colors are different (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/8) for an explanation of this).

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  PDF[WeibullDistribution[1/#, 10 #], x] & /@ Range[2, 5]], {x, 0.1, 5}]
```

[image]

As noted in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html), `Plot` and related functions quite happily draw multiple lines if they are given a list of functions (or data in the case of `ListPlot` and friends) as their first argument.

Notice the use of [`Map` (`/@`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) and a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) to avoid having to type out the `WeibullDistribution` bit of the code multiple times. ([This page in the documentation will be useful in this regard](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html).)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the Map documentation, that is very useful! In this case you used "#" for both parameters. But, let's say I would want to map 1 list of values to the first parameter, and one to the second parameter, how would I do this?

Comment: @Chris You should look up `Apply` (`@@`) and apply at level 1 (`@@@`). A simple example which you can extend to your case is the following: `Clear[f];f[#1, #2] & @@@ Transpose[{Range[5], Range[6, 10]}]`

Comment: @Chris: Also have a look at `MapThread`. But this is really a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to write Verbeia's code:

```
Plot[#, {x, 0.1, 5}] & @
  Array[PDF[WeibullDistribution[1/#, 10 #], x] &, 4, 2]
```