# "Not a valid Filling specification" error

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

I have a function, which plots the given function array `f`. This is a part of the function:

```
Plot[-f, {x,0,2}, Filling->{1->{2}}, PlotStyle->Green]
```

When I specify `{x^2, 2x}` as the function `f`, I get the errors `"2 must be an integer between 1 and 1. "` and `"{2} is not a valid Filling specification."`. I get this error because I have a minus sign in front of the argument `f`. If I plot `{-x^2,-2x}` then everything is fine. So how to multiply everything in `f` by -1 without getting these errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to evaluate the first argument of `Plot` before sampling the specific datapoints, as the multiplication (the minus sign before the list of functions) does **not** get thread over the list by default, as `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll`. This means that your example `Plot` is practically called with only **one** function (which is a `List`) and therefore the `Filling` specification does not make sense. Discussed in more detail [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/89).

```
Plot[Evaluate[-{x^2, 2 x}], {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

This effectively equals the following (note that the - signs are in front of the individual functions):

```
Plot[{-x^2, -2 x}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

Both produce the following correct plot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

As István Zachar describes this is an evaluation problem.  I recommend however using a different form:

```
Plot[-f, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotStyle -> Green, Evaluated -> True]
```

This is superior to `Evaluate[-f]` in that the `Plot` variable (`x`) is correctly localized.

For example:

```
f := {x^2, 2 x};

x = 7; (* accidental definition *)

Plot[-f, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotStyle -> Green, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The other method fails:

```
Plot[Evaluate[-f], {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 for the foolproof method. Am I right in assuming that this is an undocumented option (I never heard of before)?

Comment: @István as far as I know it is undocumented, but it [has been around for a while.](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/May/msg00866.html)

Comment: We really need a comprehensive list of undocumented symbols and string options. I'm not sure adding `Evaluated` to this [huge and messy list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions) would help anyone...