# why the variable scope is not local when using evaluate to plot multicurve?

Tags: plotting, scoping, variable

I noticed a surprising problem when using evaluate to plot multicurve, "evaluate" function actually consider global variable first, not the local! I can illustrate the problem using the following simple example, say I want to plot multicurve Z=1*x^2, 3*x^2, 5*x^2, 7*x^2 using a two-variate function Z[x_,y_]:=y*x^2, the following will work:

```
Z[x_, y_] := y*x^2;
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Z[x, y], {y, 1, 7, 2}]], {x, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle-> {Purple, Red, Green, Blue}, 
PlotLegend -> Table[Style[SequenceForm["y=", y], Bold, 16], {y, 1, 7, 2}], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "Z"}]
```

But inserting a global variable (say x=1) before the plot command will over ride the local variable used for the plot range ({x,1,5} in the example). So Instead of plotting Z=1*x^2, 3*x^2, 5*x^2, 7*x^2, it will plot Z=1*1^2, 3*1^2, 5*1^2, 7*1^2. Isn't this counter-intuitive?

I think the ListPlot is more intuitive in terms of variable scope. Because the following implementation using ListPlot is not interfered by global variable x.

```
ListPlot[Table[Table[{x, Z[x, y]}, {x, 1, 5, 0.1}], {y, 1, 7, 2}], 
PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Purple, Red, Green, Blue}, Joined -> True,
PlotLegend -> Table[Style[SequenceForm["y=", y], Bold, 16], {y, 1, 7, 2}],
AxesLabel -> {"x", "Z"}]
```

Comment: Its the Evaluate that is forcing the early resolution of x.

Comment: Try wrapping the `Plot` command with `Block[{x},....]`.

Comment: For this reason it is better to use the option `Evaluated -> True` instead of `Evaluate`

Comment: To Simon Woods: Thanks for mentioning the "option" approach, unfortunately it will interfere with showing the PlotLegend: only one curve is shown in the legend if I use the option approach. Any further suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, wrap it up with Block[] or Module[] will work, just need to know this problem in priori :) Thanks to Ymareth and kale.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can localize x using...`Module[{x}, Plot[Evaluate[Table[Z[x,y]...`

Comment: Can you expand a bit ? It is too vague ...

Comment: I think Mr Wizard has done a better job that I can in the time available (though I could have done better than the one liner!).

Answer (score 2):

[`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html) specifically operates to force evaluation:

> `Evaluate[expr]`
>   causes expr to be evaluated even if it appears as the argument of a function whose attributes specify that it should be held unevaluated.
>
> You can use Evaluate to override HoldFirst, etc. attributes of built-in functions.
>
> Evaluate only overrides HoldFirst, etc. attributes when it appears directly as the head of the function argument that would otherwise be held.

[`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html) has the Attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) so that resolution of global assignments does not take place preemptively, but you are overriding that behavior.

The simplest workaround is to use the undocumented option `Evaluated -> True` which I prefer<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121),[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7561/121),[(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6100/121),[(4)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47968/121)</sup> specifically because it *does* respect scoping:

```
x = "Fail!";

Plot[Sinc[x*Range[3]], {x, -5, 5}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

If you prefer not to use undocumented functionality you can use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html), as `Plot` likely does internally:

```
Block[{x},
  Plot[Sinc[x*Range[3]] // Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}]
]
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Wizard for the detailed explaination!

Comment: @lychee You're welcome, but I can't help noticing you Accepted the other answer instead.  May I know why?

Comment: I could only accept one answer. So first come, first serve. I would accept both if I could. BTW, you have soooooo many points :)

Comment: @lychee That's your prerogative.  Please don't take my inquiry as coercion.  It's not about the points these days, not that it every really was, but helping people.  In this case I was a little surprised and disappointed because I don't feel that Ymareth ever answered your question: he never explained *why* the variable was not localized.  Further I felt if it came down to solutions rather than answering the question that I had the better one.  I still do.  That's *my* prerogative. :^)