# Normal[Series[ ]] does not give a normal expression

Tags: plotting, evaluation

Let us say I want to show how the Taylor's series for Sin behaves:

```
In[94]:= Plot[Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]], {x, -π, π}]

During evaluation of In[94]:= General::ivar: -3.14146 is not a valid variable. >>    
During evaluation of In[94]:= General::ivar: -3.14146 is not a valid variable. >>    
During evaluation of In[94]:= General::ivar: -3.14146 is not a valid variable. >>    
During evaluation of In[94]:= General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

However, if I just evaluate

```
In[95]:= Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]]

Out[95]= x - x^3/6

In[96]:= Plot[x - x^3/6, {x, -π, π}]

Out[96]=
```

[image]

It works fine. What is going on? I am doing this because I want to insert the plot in a Manipulate and then see how the functions behave with more terms of the series.

**Update:**

Using the answer, I can do

```
Plot[Evaluate@Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]], {x, -π, π}]
```

However, if I try to compare as in

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Evaluate@Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]]}, {x, -π, π}]
```

it doesn't work while the explicit
`Plot[{Sin[x], x - x^3/6}, {x, -π, π}]` does.

Answer (score 16):

As kguler shows this is an evaluation order problem.

I recommend a different form however:

```
Plot[
  {Sin[x], Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]]},
  {x, -π, π},
  Evaluated -> True
]
```

For `Plot` the undocumented option `Evaluated` is superior because the plotting variable (`x`) is still correctly localized, therefore this method works even if you set a global value e.g. `x = 1` before plotting.

You asked why this doesn't work:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Evaluate@Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]]}, {x, -π, π}]
```

This fails because as [the `Evaluate` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html#306468591) under Possible Issues states:

> Evaluate works only on the first level, directly inside a held
>   function:

```
Hold[f[Evaluate[1 + 2]]]
```

> ```
> Out[1]= Hold[f[Evaluate[1 + 2]]]
> ```

Comment: I think the `Evaluated` option deserves a short entry in our new blog

Comment: Too bad `Evaluated` option doesn't exist for e.g. `LogPlot` or `ListPlot`, so one is forced to wrap the argument in `Evaluate[]` call.

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
 Plot[Evaluate@Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]], {x, -π, π}]
```

or

```
 Plot[#, {x, -π, π}] &@Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]]
```

or

```
 Plot[Normal[Series[Sin[y], {y, 0, 5}]] /. y -> x, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

to force evaluation in the appropriate order.

EDIT:

```
Plot[Evaluate@{Sin[x], Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
Plot[{Sin[x], Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, Evaluated->True]
Plot[{Sin[x], #}, {x, -Pi, Pi}] &@Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]]
Plot[{Sin[x], Normal[Series[Sin[y], {y, 0, 3}]] /. y -> x}, {x, -Pi,  Pi}]
```

all give

[image]

EDIT 2: The error message

```
 General::ivar: "-3.14146 is not a valid variable."
```

suggests why `Plot[Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]` does not work. Namely, as `Plot` plugs numerical values `x0` from the range `(-Pi,Pi)` in its first argument, the expression  `Series[Sin[x0], {x0, 0, 5}]]` becomes an invalid expression.

EDIT 3: The option setting `Evaluated->True` in  Mr.Wizard is most straightforward approach. The default setting for that option

```
 Options[Plot,Evaluated]
 (* ==> Automatic *)
```

By making the default setting for this option `True` using

```
SetOptions[Plot, Evaluated -> True];
```

you can use `Plot[...]` as usual.

An example:

```
 s = DSolve[y'[x] == 1/(1 + y[x]), y, x]; 
 Plot[ y[x] /. s /. C[1] -> Range[0, 5], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: And why is `Evaluate` required?

Comment: Plot[Evaluate@Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}] but if I try to do both as Plot[{Sin[x], 
  Evaluate@Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], it doesn't work while Plot[{Sin[x], x - x^3/6}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}] does.

Comment: Do I need to edit my answer to say *different form which he did not originally show but has now edited his question to include*?  :^)

Comment: @rcollyer, good question ... but I am afraid because of my limited understanding Mma evaluation sequence I can only guess that it has to do with the fact `Plot` has `HoldAll` attribute :) Perhaps comments and answers on [SE question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605635/990168) may provide more concrete clues.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I was trying to make sense of your comment for the last 15 minutes ... which seemed puzzling as your answer did not show on my screen despite several edits and screen refreshes that I made during the last several hours. I will delete the part in my post that uses the `Evaluated` option.

Comment: It is precisely because of the `HoldAll` attribute, and the only reason I brought it up was in the spirit of "teaching people to fish." In other words, if you had mentioned `HoldAll` it would have sent people looking for that in the docs. You already had my +1.