# Defining a function using Series?

Tags: function-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General::ivar is not a valid variable when plotting - what actually causes this and how to avoid it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this)

I need to define a function using the output of series, i.e.

```
 f[x_,M_]:= Normal[Series[Sin[x],{x,0,M}]];
```

Now, for reasons explained in [Normal[Series[ ]] does not give a normal expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7559/normalseries-does-not-give-a-normal-expression) that I can't fully understand (due inexperience and lack of time), the above code does not work as is.

I've managed to use `f` within other functions, like

```
 InverseLaplaceTransform[#,s,t] & @ f[s,M]
```

where `M` is given, but failing when trying to evaluate, i.e.

```
In[1]:= f[x_,m_]:= Normal[Series[Sin[x],{x,0,m}]];

In[2]:= f[x,3]

Out[2]= x - x^3/6

In[3]:= f[2,3]

General::ivar: 2 is not a valid variable. >>
General::ivar: 2 is not a valid variable. >>

Out[3]= Sin[2]
```

In a nutshell, is there a way to use `f` like a "normal" function?

Comment: what do you mean "the above code does not work as is."? what do you do and what goes wrong? (apart from a syntax error due to a missing bracket, which I suppose you forgot to paste).

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi `M=4` or 5 to say something. I thought it was implied in the context of `Series`, silly me.

Comment: @acl I chose a bad example. I wasn't able to do numeric evaluation of `f` and hence do any stuff that needed evaluation.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi Good thing I wrote `Sin[x]` instead of `g[x]` then ;)

Comment: @Manuel perhaps you could update the question to indicate what the problem is, then? by, eg, adding "for instance, `f[3,3]` fails with...". this would make it easier to locate (this is a common problem, so others will definitely have the same question)

Comment: @acl Done. Thanks for the suggestion. Somehow it feels _dishonest_ (reputation wise), but you are completely right.

Comment: No reason to feel bad about clarifying the question, it will probably help others in the future this way. Just think of the happiness you are spreading by doing this :)

Comment: This is the same issue as in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1301/5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In a nutshell, is there a way to use `f` like a "normal" function?

If you want to be able to evaluate `f` for *numerical* values of `x` as well, then your definition as is won't work. One way to go about it is to expand `Sin[]` with a dummy variable before passing to it the value of `x`. Consider, for instance

```
f[x_, m_Integer] := (Normal[Series[Sin[\[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], 0, m}]] /. \[FormalX] -> x)
```

Here, `\[FormalX]` is what's called as a ["formal symbol"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264), which *cannot* be assigned values (accidentally or otherwise); `Series[]` however still knows how to treat it as a dummy variable, which one can then replace with an actual number after `Normal[]` does its work.

Comment: That was **exactly** what I meant. Thanks a lot J.M.

Answer (score 6):

If I define

```
f[x_, M_] := Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, M}]]
```

(note the extra ']') then, for instance,

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[f[s, 5] , s, t]
```

returns
`(* \[Delta]^\[Prime](t)-1/6 \[Delta]^(3)(t)+1/120 \[Delta]^(5)(t) *)`

As it should?

Comment: You are correct. It was a bad example. I apologize.