# How can I plot a function that is the sum of another function?

Tags: plotting, summation, broken-code

I plotted `m[t]`, but actually what I want to plot is `g[t]`, which is a summation of `m[t]` from 0 to 19 seconds. But when I plot `g[t]`, I get dots. On the picture, what I want is on the right, I don't want the dots, so I guess list plot is not the way to go. How should I plot g to look like the picture I have to the right;

[image]

#### EDIT

My code;

```
period = 1;                                     
beta = 0.05;
An = List[{-1 , 1, -1, +1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1}];

sinch[t_] := (Sin[(Pi*t - t*period)/period])/(Pi* t);                                 
m[t_] := 
  An * sinch[t] * (Cos[(Pi*beta*t - t*period) / period] / 
    (1 - (4*beta^2 * (t - t*period)^2 )/period^2 )); 

Plot[{m[t]}, {t , 0, 19}]        

g = Sum[m[t], {t, 1, 20}];
ListPlot[g]
```

Comment: Can you post your code here, not a snapshot? P.S. maybe `Sum` instead of `sum`?

Comment: *Almost* answerable if not for missing code.

Comment: If you define `m[t]` as `m[t_] := sinch[t]*(Cos[(Pi*beta*t - t*period)/ period]/(1 - (4*beta^2*(t - t*period)^2)/period^2));`, then the plot `Plot[m[t], {t, 0, 19}]` looks very much like what you show on the right of the image shown in your question

Comment: I voted to leave closed because `Total[m[t], 2]` is _almost_ zero everywhere. Try `Plot[Total[m[t], 2], {t, 0, 19}]` to see it

Comment: Yves Klett, your way gives me what I want for m(t), but then you did not multiply with the "An" , because An comes out of the summation and multiplies at the end.

Answer (score 3):

- Your usage of [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sum.html) gives you only a single sum, not a cumulative one.  I shall assume that you want to integrate your function.
- Your function produces many identical lines; I shall keep only two unique ones.
- You have an extraneous [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/List.html) level in `An`; I shall remove it.
- You probably want the option `PlotRange -> All` in the `Plot`, so that you see everything.
- I shall add `Evaluated -> True` to give independently styled lines.  See: [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121).  I use `Evaluated -> True` rather than `Evaluate` to properly localize the plot variable.[<sup>(1)</sup>](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7561/121) [<sup>(2)</sup>](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121)

Code:

```
period = 1;
beta = 0.05;
An = {-1, 1};

sinch[t_] := (Sin[(Pi*t - t*period)/period])/(Pi*t);

m[t_] := An*sinch[t]*(Cos[(Pi*beta*t - t*period)/
       period]/(1 - (4*beta^2*(t - t*period)^2)/period^2));

Block[{t},
  g[t_] = Integrate[m[t], t] // Chop;
]

Plot[m[t], {t, 0, 19}, PlotRange -> All, Evaluated -> True]

Plot[g[t], {t, 0, 19}, PlotRange -> All, Evaluated -> True]
```

Result:

[image]

[image]