# Regarding Evaluated True

Tags: evaluation, undocumented, backslide

Done a bit of reading: [Normal[Series[ ]] does not give a normal expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7559/normalseries-does-not-give-a-normal-expression/7561#7561)

Regarding the Evaluated->True, consider:

```
Plot[Evaluate[0 + {Sin[x], Cos[x]}], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

But now let's see what Evaluated->True does.

```
Plot[0 + {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, 
 Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Why the difference?

Comment: This appears to be a bug. At some point during the plot creation (inside ``System`ProtoPlotDump`iPlot``) the `Filling` option value is processed to generate a full filling description for each plotted curve. This process does not take into account the `Evaluated` option and so sees only a single expression in your second example, and therefore only creates a `Filling` specification for one curve. I suggest you submit a bug report to Wolfram.

Comment: Weird. `Evaluated` does not appear to be an option listed in the Documentation Center for `Plot`, and `Evaluated` does not even appear to have a documentation entry (but it's obviously built-in and recognized).

Comment: `Options[Plot]` listing includes `Evaluated -> Automatic`

Comment: Both `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, Evaluated -> True]` and `Plot[{0 + Sin[x], 0 + Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, Evaluated -> True]` work as expected. The problem with `Evaluated` appears to be related to the depth of the expression to be `Evaluated`.

Comment: @SimonWoods `ProtoPlotDump` sounds like an imprecation to me :)

Comment: In version 8.0.4 I get the expected result in all cases, [proof](http://i.imgur.com/Wp74Avj.png). So it appears to be another new-in-v.10 bug.

Comment: The strange behavior persists in Version 11.1 (Windows 10 - 64 Bit).