# Making code faster?

Tags: plotting, functions, performance-tuning, timing

I am dealing with a very simple code, which turns to be slow when I try to plot the final Piecewise function. Is the code computing back again the integral iteratively rather than just substituting d=2 and easily plotting?

```
AbsoluteTiming[g[t_, d_] = Integrate[d*Sin[t - t1]*f[t1], {t1, 0, t}, 
Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals && d \[Element] Reals]] 
AbsoluteTiming[f[t1_] = Piecewise[{{-t1^2, 0 <= t1 <= 3}, {t1, t1 > 3}}]]
AbsoluteTiming[g[t, d]]
Plot[g[t, 2], {t, 0, 5}]
```

Even if I use /.d->2 inside Plot it is very slow.

So what I did is the following, trying to avoid the Evaluate and understand why I had problems (which seem to come from that 4th raw `g[t,d]`. Two ways worked well: 1) changing the order of the rows

```
AbsoluteTiming[
f[t1_] = Piecewise[{{-t1^2, 0 <= t1 <= 3}, {t1, t1 > 3}}]]
AbsoluteTiming[
g[t_, d_] = 
Integrate[d*Sin[t - t1]*f[t1], {t1, 0, t}, 
Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals && d \[Element] Reals]]
AbsoluteTiming[g[t, d]]
Plot[g[t, 2], {t, 0, 5}]
```

or 2) changing the initial definition of `g[t_,d_]` into `g[t_]`deleting `g[t,d]` and defining a new function:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
g[t_] = Integrate[d*Sin[t - t1]*f[t1], {t1, 0, t}, 
Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals && d \[Element] Reals]]
AbsoluteTiming[
f[t1_] = Piecewise[{{-t1^2, 0 <= t1 <= 3}, {t1, t1 > 3}}]]
h[t_, d_] = g[t]
Plot[h[t, 2], {t, 0, 5}]
```

I think Mathematica gets confused because of that `g[t,d]` definition after `g[t_,d_]`? Anyone can explain why?

Comment: If I define 
  
    g[t_] 

rather than g[t_,d_] and then a new function, such as h[t_,d_]=g[t_] and then plot h[t,2], it works. Why?

Comment: `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll` and as the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot) will tell you in the section *Detail & Options* sometimes an `Evaluate` will help, so this runs fast: `Plot[ Evaluate@g[ t, 2 ], {t,0,5}]`.

Comment: Have a look at [88571](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88571/764).

Comment: You could also evaluate at the beginning `SetOptions[Plot, Evaluated -> True];`. Or, the shortest way: `Plot @@ {g[t, 2], {t, 0, 5}}`, which is fast because of what @gwr told you.

Comment: @Rolf Still learning something new every day: Where is the option `Evaluated` to be found in the documentation? It is neither listed by itself, nor under `Plot`or `Graphics` nor to be found in the tutorials about evaluation...

Comment: @Rolf One should note, that there seem to be deeper issues with that undocumented option. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66336/764). So using `Evaluate` to me seems saver.

Comment: @gwr, `Evaluated` is an *undocumented* option, but has been there for quite a while.

Comment: @J.M. So I learn, but there seem to be issues, cf. the linked post?

Comment: @gwr, correct, and yet another example of *caveat emptor* when using undocumented functionality.

Comment: @gwr can you explain me that Evaluate@? I am looking for syntax and i cant find anything about the use of @ symbol

Comment: `f@expr` is a [Short Form](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html) for the  [`Prefix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prefix.html) notation.

Comment: For reference: `f[x]`, `f @ x`, and `x // f` are equivalent expressions.

Comment: You should also closely look at `Set` and `SetDelayed`. See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/764).