# Help on evaluation control?

Tags: evaluation

I want to plot series of slopes:

x, 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x, 6x...

I'm trying to do this:

```
a = Range[10]; c = 0; Clear[b]
f := ToExpression[ToString[b] <> ToString[a[[c = c + 1]]]]
```

So everytime I input `f`, it gives me:

```
b1
b2
b3
b4
...
```

Now I want to assign every bn to one of the plots:

```
b1=Plot[x,{x,1,10}]
b2=Plot[2x,{x,1,10}]
b3=Plot[3x,{x,1,10}]
b4=Plot[4x,{x,1,10}]
...
```

I've tried to do this:

```
f=Plot[x,{x,1,10}]
```

But It will only switch the variable from the first fuction to the Plot function. How can I do to the `f`become `b1` first and then the `b1` be assigned to the Plot function? I guess it has something to do with evaluation control, something like that.

NOTE:. The ? in the title means that I'm not very sure If it's about evaluation control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought a minimal code can make a nice visualization of it:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[{Range[n] x, n x}], {x, -2, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-20, 50}}, Filling -> 0]
 , {{n, 0, "slope"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

If on the other hand you would like to plot all slopes separately, this could do:

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Plot[# x, {x, -2, 5}, Frame -> True, 
     AxesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thick], PlotStyle -> Thick, 
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-30, 80}}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Slope = " <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[16], 4], 
 ImageSize -> 900]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, It's because I'm still a little afraid of using the #'s and && and all that pattern stuff. I'm reading Leonard Shinfrin's book now.

Comment: Leonid Shifrin :)

Comment: Although Leonard evokes associations with actors that play pointy-eared highly competent aliens, which somehow resonates (in a very positive, awe-inspiring way) with my impression of Leonid ;-)

Answer (score 21):

Once again I shall recommend a different form for evaluating the first argument of `Plot`:

```
Plot[x Range[9], {x, 1, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Though the option `Evaluated` is undocumented it is superior because it works even if `x` has a global value, whereas `Plot[Evaluated[ . . . ], . . .]` will not.  That is, the `Plot` variable is correctly localized.

Comment: I always thought you would recommend `(x Range@9)~(Plot[#1, #2, Evaluated -> True] &)~{x, 1, 10}` :D

Comment: @belisarius no, of course not! ... it doesn't localize `x`. ;^p

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "correctly localized".

Comment: @Gustavo when you enter something like `x = 7; Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]` it still works because `x` is *localized* by `Plot`.  If you use `Evaluate` this breaks; e.g. `x = 7; Plot[Evaluate@Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]` you get a single horizontal line because you are effectively doing `Plot[Sin[7], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`.  On the other hand, `Evaluated -> True` localizes `x` before evaluation:  `x = 7; Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Evaluated -> True]`

Answer (score 5):

It's slightly simpler if you're willing to use `b[1]` instead of `b1`:

```
Do[b[i] = Plot[i x, {x, 1, 10}],{i, 10}]

b[3]
```

[image]

If you're really keen on using `b1`, you can do something like:

```
Do[
   Set[Evaluate[Symbol["b" <> ToString[i]]], 
       Plot[i x, {x, 1, 10}]], 
   {i, 10}]

b3
```

[image]