# How do I use Map for a function with two arguments?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I'm a newbie who tries to be a good boy, and use `Map` instead of writing out a list of functions.

I have a table I want to `Map` onto:

```
ratios = Table[10^(n/10), {n, 0, 10}]
```

and a function

```
rp[x_, r_] := 1000 x (r + 1)/(r + x)
```

which I want to `Plot` for the 11 ratios, for `x in [0, 1]`:

```
Plot[Map[rp, ratios], {x, 0, 1}]
```

This doesn't work, and I can guess why: `rp` requires two arguments, and MMA probably doesn't know which one is the ratio. And `x` also doesn't appear as a parameter. How do I fix this?

Comment: You may find [this discussion](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node438.html) relevant.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can create a pure function that maps only on `ratio` as follows:

```
Plot[Map[rp[x, #] &, ratios], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

You will need the `Evaluated -> True` option in order for `Plot` to view the functions as several different ones and plot them in different colours.

---

You can also bypass having to use `Map` by creating your function with the `Listable` attribute. For example:

```
rp2[x_] := Function[{r}, 1000 x (r + 1)/(r + x), Listable]
Plot[rp2[x][ratios], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

This returns the same output as above, but automatically maps (threads) over lists.

Comment: The `Evaluated->True` works fine for the `PlotStyle` option but doesn't work for the `PlotLegend` option, any clue why? Or has any other trick has to be used?

Comment: @Öskå Do you have an example? This works: `Plot[Table[Sin[k x], {k, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Evaluated -> True]`

Comment: Using *Mathematica 8* `PlotLegend -> {"sine", "sine", "sine"}]` only shows "sine" one time: http://imgur.com/1uyciA9

Comment: @Öskå Ugh... that's using the old `PlotLegends` package, which is hideous. I have no idea how to make it fix and I'm not going to touch that with a 10 ft pole :( Perhaps you might be able to use [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/5), which is a far better alternative for _Mathematica_ 8.

Comment: mhm thanks :-) I'll take a look at that long answer tomorow. Once again, thanks :-)

Answer (score 12):

This is a direct fulfilling of your attempts :

```
Plot[ rp[x, #] & /@ ratios, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

`rp[x, #] &` denotes a function depending on the second argument in `rp`,  while `/@` is a shorthand for `Map`, i.e  `rp[x, #] & /@ ratios` means `Map[ rp[ x,#] &, ratios ]`.

Here is another way to plot your functions  without `Map` :

```
Plot[ Evaluate[ Table[ rp[x, a], {a, ratios}]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

`Evaluate` serves here for plotting curves in various colors.

You can plot graphs of the functions as a family of curves in three dimensions using 
`ParametricPlot3D`.

```
ParametricPlot3D[ Evaluate[ Table[{x, a, rp[x, a]}, {a, ratios}]],
                  {x, 0, 10},  BoxRatios -> {10, 10, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: @stevenvh You've got another way of doing your task in my answer without `Map`.

Comment: When using `Evaluate` in this fashion you need to guard against a global value of `x`.  Add something about this to your answer and you'll have my vote.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Do you like `Block[{x}, ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[{x, a, rp[x, a]}, {a, ratios}]], {x, 0, 10},   BoxRatios -> {10, 10, 5}] ]`  more ?  Otherwise, I'd choose `Evaluated->True` in `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: `Block`, `Evaluated -> True`, or simply the mention of the issue would do.  You have my vote now anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Some things to think about:

```
rp[x_, r_] := 1000 x (r + 1)/(r + x)

rp[x, #] & /@ ratios

Outer[rp, {x}, ratios][[1]]

Table[rp[x, i], {i, ratios}]

Block[{rp},
  rp[x, ratios] // Thread
]
```

And [Formal Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) (looks better in the Notebook):

```
ClearAll[rp]
rp[r_] := 1000 \[FormalX] (r + 1)/(r + \[FormalX])

Plot[rp /@ ratios, {\[FormalX], 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this (see [Parameterized function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121) and [Currying in *Mathematica*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5686494/618728)):

```
ClearAll[rp]
rp[x_][r_] := 1000 x (r + 1)/(r + x)

Plot[rp[x] /@ ratios, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Be sure to read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121) for an explanation of `Evaluated -> True`.

Comment: +1 Very nice: `Plot[Outer[rp, {x}, ratios], {x, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 6):

When using `Evaluated->True` the plot legends to not display or display only one item. The answer by Artes of using the `Evaluate` function on the first argument to `Plot` will also fix the issue with plot legends, so their answer is the best from that perspective.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Map[rp[x, #] &, ratios]], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

This produces

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! This looks like an extended comment on the accepted answer; so make sure to reference it (e.g. "Fixing the PlotLegends issue in rm -rf's answer, ... " so this answer can stand on its own.