# How can I highlight one function in the Plot of a list?

Tags: plotting

I've got a Plot of a list of functions from [this previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/how-do-i-use-map-for-a-function-with-two-arguments/8149#comment23240_8149) of mine.

```
rp[x_, r_] := 1000 x (r + 1)/(r + x)
ratios = Table[10^n, {n, -2, 2, 4/10}]
Plot[Map[rp[x, #] &, ratios], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Now I want the sixth function, where ratio = 1, to be plotted with a `PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness` parameter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I prefer using `Style` in cases like this.

```
rp[x_, r_] := 1000 x (r + 1)/(r + x)

ratios = Table[10^n, {n, -2, 2, 4/10}];

em = Style[#, AbsoluteThickness[4]] &;

Plot[
 MapAt[em, rp[x, #] & /@ ratios, 6],
 {x, 0, 1},
 Evaluated -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[
 MapAt[em, rp[x, #] & /@ ratios, {{4}, {6}}],
 {x, 0, 1},
 Evaluated -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

This works for styling directives except for color (by default), but colors are overridden by the default `PlotStyle` colors because of the output form, which is:

```
Style[{(* PlotStyle directive *), Line[. . .]}, (* Style directive *)]
```

If for whatever reason the `Style` method is desirable for colors as well one could use:

```
red = Style[#, Red, Thick] &;

Plot[
  MapAt[red, x Range@5, {{2}, {4}}],
  {x, 1, 10},
  Evaluated -> True
] /. Style[{__, L__Line}, s__] :> Style[{L}, s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This discards all `PlotStyle` directives and keeps the `Style` directives for lines with `Style`.

Comment: Hi Wizard. Nice, compact code. I like it, thanks. +1 for now, later maybe more :-)

Comment: +1, I did not know `Plot` accepted `Style` as a function.

Comment: @rcollyer it does, but beware that Plot's own styling overrides this so I use it only for things like `Dashed` and `Thick`, *not* color.

Comment: Kudos - is this documented somewhere?

Comment: You meant `em` (instead of `style`) in the last example.(+1)

Comment: @kguler thanks; I changed `style` to `em` to be less like `Style`, and forgot the second case.

Comment: @YvesKlett probably so, but after years of trying I'm still not great at finding things in the Documentation system; I have sympathy for the neophytes who post "obvious" questions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard on the other hand I think the documentation is brimming with excellent examples and the integration of those (just evaluate in place) is way better than copy&paste orgies known from other systems/workflows.

Comment: @steven thanks for the Accept; I added a supplemental example should you need it.

Answer (score 10):

You can generate a list of additional style directives to go with your `Plot`, e.g. like this

```
rp[x_, r_] := 1000 x (r + 1)/(r + x)
ratios = Table[10^n, {n, -2, 2, 4/10}];
styles = If[# == 1, Thick, Thin] & /@ ratios;
Plot[Map[rp[x, #] &, ratios], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> styles]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
 Plot[Map[rp[x, #] &, ratios], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Map[If[#1 == 1, AbsoluteThickness[3], Automatic] &, ratios]]
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Yves' answer, here's a way to modify the $n^\mathrm{th}$ line (corresponding to the $n^\mathrm{th}$ element of `ratio`) as a post-processing step:

```
Plot[Map[rp[x, #] &, ratios], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]  /. 
    {x___, y : {Hue[__], __} ..} :> {x, MapAt[Insert[#, Thickness[Large], 2] &, {y}, 3]}
```

[image]

This modifies the 3rd line (given as the third argument of `MapAt`). As always, structural manipulations are made on the `FullForm` of the expression, so if you have a more complicated or different structure, you'll have to exploit that accordingly.

Here's the above in a `Manipulate` to play with:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[Map[rp[x, #] &, ratios], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True] /. 
        {x___, y : {Hue[__], __} ..} :> {x, MapAt[Insert[#, Thickness[Large], 2] &, {y}, i]}, 
    {{i, 1}, 1, Length@ratios, 1}
]
```

[image]

Comment: ´s nice! A possible (longterm) conflict may arise if the output of `Plot` changes in the future. Happened to me at some major version switch and resulted in a lengthyish bug hunt ;-)

Comment: Heh yeah, that's why I put in the statutory warning that it is based on the `FullForm` and different structures will need to be handled differently :)

Comment: The severability clause is (and was) duly noted. Just wanted to drive the point home ´cause a thing like this once came back and bit me ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett it only bit you once? Lucky. I've got code written for 4 major releases, and I pray every time I have to run something from an older version. Of course, some of the prayer is due to the difference in coding ability between then and now, but I digress. :)

Comment: @rcollyer not once, alas, but hacky solutions tend to [HCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire) just a bit more often and then you cannot even blame WRI...

Comment: @YvesKlett my wife actually had a computer catch fire while she was using it.

Comment: @rcollyer hot darn! A real power user, then ;-)  My graphics card sometimes also seems to be responsible for a nontrivial part global warming (thank you, CUDA).

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Linux and using Yves excellent answer I get the following output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which has a very high contrast between the emphasised line and the rest.

Using a combination of thick and dashed lines seems to my eye to give more pleasing result:

```
rp[x_, r_] := 1000 x (r + 1)/(r + x)
ratios = Table[10^n, {n, -2, 2, 4/10}];
styles = If[# == 1, Thick, Dashed] & /@ ratios;
Plot[Map[rp[x, #] &, ratios], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> styles]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This doesn't present a different solution, does it?

Comment: @stevenvh Thanks, I forgot to paste the modified code.