# Controlling point size and color in two list plots rendered by Show

Tags: plotting, graphics

Is there a good way to control both the size of a point and its color in a listplot? I am trying to create a 'projected band structure' plot, which involves putting points onto a graph and controlling their size, and ideally their color. I have been able to control the size using the method suggested in: [Control PointSize on a ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60841/control-pointsize-on-a-listplot). This leads to random colors, which is not desired.

```
Photon = Sqrt[1 + x^2];
Exciton = 2;
Matrix = {{Photon, 0.15}, {0.15, Exciton}};
UpperBranch = Table[{x, Part[Eigenvalues[Matrix], 1]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}];
LowerBranch = Table[{x, Part[Eigenvalues[Matrix], 2]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}];
UpperBranchPhotonComponent = 
  Table[{x, (Part[Normalize[Part[Eigenvectors[Matrix], 1]], 1])^2}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}];
UpperBranchExcitonComponent = 
  Table[{x, (Part[Normalize[Part[Eigenvectors[Matrix], 1]], 2])^2}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}];
LowerBranchPhotonComponent = 
  Table[{x, (Part[Normalize[Part[Eigenvectors[Matrix], 2]], 1])^2}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}];
LowerBranchExcitonComponent = 
  Table[{x, (Part[Normalize[Part[Eigenvectors[Matrix], 2]], 2])^2}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}];

Show[
  Plot[Eigenvalues[Matrix], {x, 0, 3}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thin, Black}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Scientific"], 
  ListPlot[List /@ UpperBranch, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Black, 
    ImageSize -> 500, 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize /@ (Abs[Last /@ UpperBranchPhotonComponent]/75), 
    PlotMarkers -> None, 
    PlotTheme -> "Scientific"], 
  ListPlot[List /@ LowerBranch, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Black, 
    ImageSize -> 500, 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize /@ (Abs[Last /@ LowerBranchPhotonComponent]/75), 
    PlotMarkers -> None, 
    PlotTheme -> "Scientific"], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

The result is shown below;

[image]

Everything is working basically correctly, but I would like to have all the points be a single color, and this is proving to be difficult. Is there a simpler way to do this altogether, and especially a way to allow the color to be specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to take control of the elements you want to control is to specify them as graphics primitives in an Epilog option of the Eigenvalues plot.

```
Plot[Eigenvalues[Matrix], {x, 0, 3},
  Epilog ->
    {Red,
     MapThread[{PointSize[#1], Point[#2]} &, 
       {Abs[Last /@ UpperBranchPhotonComponent]/75, UpperBranch}],
     MapThread[{PointSize[#1], Point[#2]} &, 
       {Abs[Last /@ LowerBranchPhotonComponent]/75, LowerBranch}]},
  PlotStyle -> {Thin, Black},
  GridLinesStyle -> Black,
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Very elegant! I had thought of creating the points through a do/for loop but that was not working out very well either. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @speeze. I'm glad my answer helps you. Although you have too few reputation points to up-vote, you can further extend your thanks by accepting the answer. Just click on the check mark on the left side of the answer below the down arrow.