# Change the point size in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Suppose I have data like this

`ListPlot[{{1,2,3},{3,2,1}}]`.
I would like to change the point size of only first two points in both datasets. Although there are many examples similar to this, for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60841/control-pointsize-on-a-listplot) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7408/listplot-with-plotmarkers-determined-by-point), all of them talk about improving the point size on single dataset. However, in my case I have two datasets.

So, my question is how to control the pointsize of each point in multiple datasets in `ListPlot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post-process the output to change the styles of selected points:

```
ListPlot[list, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}] /. 
 Point[x_] :> {x /. p : {_, _} :> If[p[[1]] <= 2, {PointSize[Large], Point[p]}, Point[p]]}
```

[image]

Create a new list wrappping desired data points with `Style`:

```
list2 = {{Style[1, Red, PointSize[Large]], Style[2, Red, PointSize[Large]], 3}, 
   {Style[3, Blue, PointSize[Large]], Style[2, Blue, PointSize[Large]], 1}};
ListPlot[list2, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]
```

> same picture