# Shrink ListPlot Marker Size to Zero

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to create a `ListPlot` where the size of each marker is controlled individually.

The best solution I have found so far is to wrap every data point in `Style` with its own `PointSize` value, as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60841/control-pointsize-on-a-listplot)

```
ListPlot[Table[Style[RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 2], PointSize[RandomReal[{0, 0.03}]]], {i, 100}]]
```

[image]

However, this type of scaling does not allow reducing the size to zero, but keeps the marker size constant at some point:

```
ListPlot[Table[Style[{i, 2}, PointSize[0.08 - 0.002*i]], {i, 50}]
```

[image]

How can I ensure that the scaling of the markers is really linear with respect to `Pointsize` all the way to zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is certainly suboptimal behavior, if not a bug. You can workaround the issue by using `PlotStyle->None` and including `Opacity[1]` in your style:

```
ListPlot[
    Table[Style[RandomReal[{-2,2},2],Opacity[1],PointSize[RandomReal[{0,0.03}]]],{i,100}],
    PlotStyle->None
]
```

[image]

And, your second example:

```
ListPlot[
    Table[Style[{i,2},Opacity[1],PointSize[0.08-0.002*i]],{i,50}],
    PlotStyle->None
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing the work around, that helped a lot :)