# Use different markers/colors in logarithmic plot depending on sign

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Suppose you have the dataset

```
xData = Table[i, {i, 1, 30}];
yData = RandomReal[{0.995, 1.005}, 30];
```

and want to plot the difference of `yData-1` on a `ListLogPlot`.

```
ListLogPlot[Transpose[{xData, yData - 1}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

Of course, there will be negative differences, hence not being plotted. If the differences' signs were unimportant one could just plot `Abs[yData-1]`. However, if the sign is important: What is a (I am sure there must be something) nice way to e.g. plot the `Abs` but use different markers for different signs. The only way I can come up with is pre-processing the data into two sets corresponding to the signs and then plot both seperately into the same graph.

Edit: I decided to accept MichaelE2's answer because I did not know anything about `VertexColor` and it could be very useful for future plotting issues. However, also all other answers are great solutions and I don't mean to depreciate their value by not accepting them - I just think that one answer should be accepted to "close" the question.

Comment: There are several very good answers so far. I would like to accept multiple ones, however not possible. So, I will just wait a few days to (i) wait for others answers (ii) think about which I will finally accept. Thanks to everyone so far!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `VertexColors` to color the individual points, since the points are all in a single `Point` in order.

```
ListLogPlot[Transpose[{xData, Abs[yData - 1]}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All] /. 
 Point[p_] :> 
   Point[p, VertexColors -> (Sign[yData - 1] /. {1 -> Black, -1 -> Red, 0 -> Blue})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Threw in the `0` case even though `0` won't be plotted by `ListLogPlot`.  One could have it print a warning, too.

Comment: Nice solution. I did not know that `VertexColors` exists. Could be helpful in future

Comment: @Lukas Thanks, and `VertexColors` is a more efficient way to color points, esp. when you have `Point[<long list of points>, VertexColors -> colors]`.

Answer (score 9):

The colors can be determined by the sign separately like this:

```
colors = Sign[yData - 1] /. {1 -> Blue, -1 -> Red};
```

In order to change the color of the individual markers we have to change the `Graphics` object that `ListLogPlot` generates. We can view that expression using

```
plot = ListLogPlot[
 Transpose[{xData, Abs[yData - 1]}],
 Joined -> True, Mesh -> All
 ];
plot // FullForm
```

We notice that the points are drawn by using the `Point` graphics primitive, like this:

```
Point[{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}]
```

In order to define the colors of the markers separately we have to create one `Point` primitive for each marker. We can do that using `Thread`:

```
Thread@Point[{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}]
(* Out: {Point[{x1,y1}],Point[{x2,y2}],...} *)
```

Now we can use `Riffle` to insert the colors.

```
plot /. p : Point[_] :> Riffle[colors, Thread[p]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, especially for your explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Fundamentally this isn't much different than what you're suggesting, as far as splitting the data into positive and negative parts,

```
xData = Table[i, {i, 1, 30}];
yData = RandomReal[{0.995, 1.005}, 30];

ListLogPlot[
 {{#1, Abs@#2}} & @@@ Transpose@{xData, yData - 1},
 PlotStyle -> (yData - 1) /. {x_Real /; Sign[x] == -1 :> Red, 
   x_Real :> Black}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, as well. That is indeed quite similar to what I thought about. However, I did not know that it's possible to use conditionals for `PlotStyle`.

Comment: It's not actually using conditionals for the plot style, it's just replacing the elements of yData with the appropriate color. What is actually fed to PlotStyle is a list of RGBColors.

Answer (score 3):

I propose the `Epilog` option

```
xData = Table[i, {i, 1, 30}];
yData = RandomReal[{0.995, 1.005}, 30];

(*Construct the colors and the point objects*)

pts = Point /@ Transpose[{xData, Log@Abs[yData - 1]}];
colors = Sign[yData - 1] /. {1 -> Blue, -1 -> Red};

(*visulization*)

ListLogPlot[
 Transpose[{xData, Abs[yData - 1]}], Joined -> True, 
  Epilog -> Prepend[Riffle[colors, pts], PointSize[Medium]]
]
```

> [image]

Comment: @Lukas, My pleasure:-) Glad to know you like it.

Answer (score 2):

[`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) can be used directly on elements of several [different](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8191/121) plot types.

```
ListPlot[
  Transpose[{xData, yData - 1}] /.
    {x_, y_?Negative} :> Style[{x, -y}, Red], 
  Joined -> True,
  Mesh -> All,
  ImageSize -> 500
]
```

[image]