# How to color the same contour line with different colors according y value

Tags: plotting, graphics

Here is an example:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[y - x^2] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: stupid example]

Because all these separate lines come from the same contour line `Sin[y - x^2] == 0`, `ColorFunction` color the contour lines as the same color. This is the correct behavior for most contour plots. However, for this example, color the same contour line with different color make sense. How can I do it in *Mathematica*?

### Update

Let's make this question even more silly, because I actually have a figure must be draw part by part. Consider following code:

```
Show[{ContourPlot[Sin[y - x^2] == 0, {x, -2, 0}, {y, -10, 10}], 
  ContourPlot[Sin[-y - x^2] == 0, {x, 0, }, {y, -10, 10}]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: stupid 3]

The question is the same, how to color the lines with different colors?

Comment: Related: [(70102)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70102/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is acceptable to order the lines by the *y* value of the first point in each contour we can use a modification of Pickett's method:

```
plot = Show[{ContourPlot[Sin[y - x^2] == 0, {x, -1, 0}, {y, -10, 10}], 
   ContourPlot[Sin[-y - x^2] == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -10, 10}]}, PlotRange -> All];

cols = {Red, Black, Blue, Orange, Green, Pink, Brown};

Normal[plot] /. {a___, l : Longest[Line[_] ..], b___} :>
  {a, Riffle[cols, {l} ~SortBy~ Extract[{1, 1, 2}] ], b}
```

[image]

Or using [xslittlegrass's `restylePlot2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59805/121) as the base method:

```
restyleWithSort[p_, op : OptionsPattern[ListLinePlot]] :=
  ListLinePlot[Cases[Normal@p, Line[x__] :> x, ∞] ~SortBy~ Extract[{1, 2}], 
   op, Options[p]]

Show[restyleWithSort /@ {
   ContourPlot[Sin[y - x^2] == 0, {x, -1, 0}, {y, -10, 10}],
   ContourPlot[Sin[-y - x^2] == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -10, 10}]
   },
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

Comment: +1, using `Normal` to flatten out `GraphicsComplex` is new to me.

Comment: Change the x range to (-2,2), a continuous line will be colored to two different colors. Because, the lowest segment only appear in the left side.

Comment: @Kattern I anticipated such problems which is why I specifically wrote "*If* it is acceptable."  This is a puzzle I haven't faced before (that I can recall) and I don't have a nice solution for it.  Sorry. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it is all right. You have already helped a lot. I can manage the special cases using `Inkscape`. Only 10% of the figures have the problem, it is about 10 figures. It is not hard to adjust them by hand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Kattern Do you know that you can [edit line colors](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/EditWolframLanguageGraphics.html) from within *Mathematica* as well?  Perhaps I should have included that in my answer but I *assumed* you were looking for a programmatic solution.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I know. Because I want to make an animation, displaying hundreds of figures in *Mathematica*  is not easy to handle. I have to export frames to image files sooner or later. Thus, I export all the figures to svg files first, and preview them in image browser to check which one needs further adjustment.

Answer (score 7):

You can manipulate the expression manually:

```
plot = ContourPlot[
   Sin[y - x^2] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -10, 10}
   ];

plot /. {a___, l : Longest[Line[_] ..], b___} :>
  {a, Riffle[Array[ColorData[97], Length@{l}], {l}], b}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In order to find the pattern it helps to look at `plot // FullForm`. `ColorData[97]` is the list of default colors for Mathematica 10. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86092/731) is another answer I wrote two days ago, which also shows how this technique can be used.

Comment: I will check the answer later. It seems I cannot get control of the color used in the lines, like `Black` for the lowest line, `Red` for the second.

Comment: @Kattern It seem that the contour lines are not produced in that order.  In your application is it acceptable to perform a simple sort on them?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I noticed that as well. And please also see the updated question.

Answer (score 5):

```
func[cplot_, cf_, s_] := With[{cp = cplot},
  pt = cp[[1, 1]];
  lines = Cases[cp, Line[x__] :> x, -1];
  max = Max[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ (Part[pt, #] & /@ lines);
  Show[Graphics[
    GraphicsComplex[pt, 
     MapThread[{cf[Abs[Rescale[#1, {Min[max], Max[max]}] - s]], Thick,
         Line[#2]} &, {max, lines}]], Frame -> True, 
    AspectRatio -> Full]]
  ]
```

For this example:

```
p1 = ContourPlot[Sin[y - x^2] == 0, {x, -1, 0}, {y, -10, 10}];
p2 = ContourPlot[Sin[-y - x^2] == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -10, 10}];
Manipulate[
 Show @@ (func[#, color, s] & /@ {p1, p2}), {{color, 
   Hue}, {Hue -> "Hue", ColorData["Rainbow"] -> "Rainbow", 
   ColorData["Pastel"] -> "Pastel"}}, {{s, 0, "invert"}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Woo, this one is pretty hard to understand.

Comment: @Kattern (i) I take each `ContourPlot` and decompose it into coordinates and contour lines (ii) in order to deal with gradient of colour varying with y, I take the maximum y for each line (which has 1-1 correspondence with line) and put in `max` (iii) I then use this (rescaled) as an argument for desired color function matched with line (iv) then recompose into `GraphicsComplex` (v) I then map to the separate plots and combine with `Show`.  I prefer Mr. Wizard's answer, and have up voted it.

Comment: @Kattern this worked nicely for this example as the separation by y was very easy but more complex examples may require other better approaches...hope it allows you to play around and get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations! The (ii) and (iii) steps are not easy to understand. I will explore your code to understand the mechanism. Thanks again!

Comment: ...and upvoted Pickett's of course (as basis)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will help in other examples but you can do it like this:

```
sol = (y /. Solve[Sin[x^2 - y] == 0, GeneratedParameters -> a] // 
     Normal) /. a -> (a &);
fun = Flatten@Table[sol, {a, -2, 1}];

p1 = Plot[fun, {x, -1, 0}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Thick]];
p2 = ContourPlot[Sin[y - x^2] == 0, {x, -1, 0}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  ContourStyle -> Black];
Show[p2, p1]
```

[image]

Comment: This one is nice if the analytical expression can be solve by `Solve`. `NSolve` in this case is not handy.

Answer (score 2):

### MeshStyle + MeshFunctions

```
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;; 15]];

ContourPlot[x , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -10, 10},  Contours->{},
 MeshFunctions -> {Sin[#2 - #^2] &}, Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> ({Thick, First[colors = RotateRight[colors]], #} &), 
 BaseStyle->FaceForm[]]
```

[image]

OP's second example can be handled in the same way using a `Piecewise` mesh function with some adjustment to ensure continuity at `0`:

```
ContourPlot[x , {x, -2, 2}, {y, -10, 10}, Contours -> {}, 
MeshFunctions -> {Piecewise[{{Sin[-#2]-Sin[#2]+Sin[#2 - #^2] , # <= 0},
  {Sin[-#2 - #^2] , # >= 0}}]&}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> ({Thick, First[colors = RotateRight[colors]], #} &),
 BaseStyle -> FaceForm[]]
```

[image]