# How to apply different colors to different contours

Tags: plotting, matlab

I have searched the forum, I hope this isn't a duplicate question. I try to apply unique color for every contour line with the same elevation. In short, I want to create a MATLAB style contour plot. Consider this code

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == a, {a, -2, 2, 0.5}], 
{x, 0,  4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]

I think this solution is lame. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: this is related (and may be deemed a duplicate) but either way will be helpful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86337/1997

Comment: I have read that post before. But I believe this is a different problem.

Comment: could you clarify what your issue is. Is it your desire to specify the colours or something else?

Comment: If we invoke the option `ContourShading -> None` we will have contours with the same color. I want to color these contours so we can distinguish them by their elevations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you might prefer this. Obviously you can change to your desired color function:

```
func[a_, b_, s_] := 
 With[{r = Range[a, b, s]}, 
  ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   Contours -> r, 
   ContourStyle -> 
    Table[{Thick, ColorData["Rainbow"][j/Length@r]}, {j, Length@r}], 
   ContourShading -> None]]
```

So, `func[-2,2,0.5]`

[image]

or `func[-1,1,0.01]`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also style individual contours using the `Contours` setting that allows each contour level to have its own directive:

> $ \{ \ldots, \{f_i ,g_i\}, \ldots \} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ $   contour level $f_i$ drawn with graphics directive $g_i$

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},
 ContourShading -> None,
 Contours -> ({#, Directive[Thickness[.015], ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-2, 2}}]@#]} & /@
   Range[-2, 2, 0.5])]
```

[image]