# How can I color the plot of the different functions in a table depending on the parameter the table uses?

Tags: plotting, color, list-manipulation

Suppose I have a simple function like $\cos(kx)$, and I am plotting a number of such functions with different values for $k$ as in:

```
Plot[Table[Cos[k x], {k, 1, 4, 1}], {x, 0, π}]
```

How can I color them depending on the $k$ parameter without setting it manually myself, as in:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Cos[k x], {k, 1, 4, 1}]], {x, 0, π},
  PlotStyle -> Table[Blend[{Blue, Red}, k/4], {k, 1, 4, 1}]]
```

?

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate[Table[Cos[k x], {k, 1, 4, 1}]], {x, 0, \[Pi]}]` automatically colors them differently for each `k`. Is that what you mean? If you want each plot colored specifically but you don't want to specify the colors "manually," then either I don't understand what you want or it cannot be accomplished.

Comment: Maybe this?: `Plot[Evaluate[Table[Style[Cos[k x], Blend[{Blue, Red}, k/4]], {k, 1, 4, 1}]], {x, 0, \[Pi]}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, that's exactly what I wanted! You got it! I'm gonna study that syntax.

Comment: I was about to suggest `Style` as @Michael just posted; see [(8191)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8191/121)

Comment: @Michael Do you think this is close enough to 8191 to be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's what I was trying to figure out. I'm generally inclined to say that if the same methods/approaches work for both questions, then they are duplicates. That criterion seems to apply here. OTOH, the particular differences of such questions occasionally lead community members to disagree with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be the desired form:

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[Table[Style[Cos[k x], Blend[{Blue, Red}, k/4]], {k, 1, 4, 1}]],
 {x, 0, π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

It may help to use `PlotLabels` and `PlotLegends` options to identify the plotted functions.

```
Plot[Evaluate[
Table[Style[Cos[k x], Blend[{Blue, Red}, k/4]], {k, 1, 4, 1}]], {x, 0, π}, 
PlotLabels -> Placed[Automatic, {Above, Below, After, Below}], 
PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```