# Time varying equation plot

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use Map for a function with two arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/how-do-i-use-map-for-a-function-with-two-arguments)

I have a function, e.g. $T(x,t) = \exp(-t)\sin(x)$ and I want to plot, on the same, or different graphs, $T$ as a function of $x$, for an array of $t$ values.

Comment: Search for `Plot` in the docs. And `Table`, `Map` or `Range` to build the array

Comment: You might also want to see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413).

Comment: You might also try things like: `Manipulate[Plot[Exp[-t]Sin[x],{x,-4Pi,4Pi},PlotRange->{-E,E}],{t,-1,1}]`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that should work.  It shows how to plot the one parameter family of functions all together or separately. Note that, although the separate 
plots look the same, the scales are different.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, plot T as a function of both t and x:

```
 Plot3D[Exp[-t] Sin[x], {t, 0, 5}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Another way is to build a function T[t] for each x, then plot the ones you want

```
 T[t_] := Table[Exp[-t] Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 0.01}]; 
 ListPlot[{T[0], T[0.5], T[1], T[1.5], T[2], T[2.5], T[3]}]
```