# Map a two argument function to every element on list

Tags: functional-style, map, argument-patterns, arguments

I'm new to use the amazing map function in Mathematica, and I've found it really elegant to  program in simple lines of code. However, I'd like to perform more elegant stuff. I've found this question, but its not what I'm trying to achieve. [How do I use Map for a function with two arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/how-do-i-use-map-for-a-function-with-two-arguments)

I want to **apply a two**, or more, **argument function** using **columns of a list as arguments**

My approach is the following:

For an arbitrary list:

```
vector = Table[   {RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {n, 0, 10} ]
```

[image]

I want to **apply the Tan[]** using **two columns** **as** an **arguments**, so I tried *unsuccessfully* writing:

```
Tan[#1/#2] & {vector[[;; , {1, 2}]]}
```

[image]

**I know** I can use **Table[]** (in a for loop way) like this to achieve my solution:

```
Table[{ Tan[vector[[n, 2]]/vector[[n, 1]]]}, {n, 1, Length[vector]}]
```

[image]

However, I'd like to master the *functional programming style*. **How can I achieve** the **same** output using **Map(/@)**

Any tutorial/book/lecture would be greatly appreciated as well.

Thanks!

Comment: `Tan[#1/#2] & @@@ vector[[;; , {1, 2}]]` would do it; [see manual](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html): `@@@` means "apply at level 1". Alternatively, `Tan[#[[1]]/#[[2]]] & /@ vector`. Maybe invert `#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]` – I'm unsure as to which one you want.

Comment: Also `Tan[vector[[All,2]]/vector[[All,1]]]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you're looking to learn more about functional style, I'll elaborate rather than just provide an answer.

We start with our table:

```
vector = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {n, 0, 10}]
```

We could either re-structure the table first, or deal with selecting which elements to apply the Tan function to later. If we restructure first, I'd actually prefer the following to what you had (`vector2` is there just so I can easily refer to this later).

```
vector2 = vector[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
```

Now, let's consider several ways to map. It's often easier to get a feel for these things by using undefined symbols in your mapping expression. So, compare what you get with these:

```
f /@ vector
(*gives something like {f[{0.408218, 0.315962, 0.472218}], ...}*)

f /@ vector2
(*gives something like {f[{0.408218, 0.315962}], ...}*)

f @@@ vector
(*{f[0.408218, 0.315962, 0.472218], ...}*)

f @@@ vector2
(*{f[0.408218, 0.315962]}*)

Map[f, vector, {-2}]
(*{f[{0.408218, 0.315962, 0.472218}]}*)

etc
```

That last form for Map is nice when it's easier to figure out where to apply a function from the "bottom" up in a structure, but in this case it's equivalent to one of the previous forms, because your structure isn't very deep.

Let's pick this expression: `f @@@ vector2`. At this point, you could define your anonymous function like you did: `Tan[#1/#2] &`, to give this:

```
Tan[#1/#2] & @@@ vector2

(*or alternatively, since vector2 was just convenience:*)
Tan[#1/#2] & @@@ vector[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
```

But, another nice thing that is often seen in a functional style is function composition. Since we already have the functions you need, specifically Divide and Tan, you don't need the Slot version. You could just do this:

```
Tan@*Divide @@@ vector[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
```

I'm not suggestion that this is *better*. Sometimes it's clearer/cleaner.

Now, if we had chosen this to start: `f /@ vector`, then we would need to use Part to extract the elements from the list:

```
Tan[#[[1]]/#[[2]]] & /@ vector
```

Comment: Excellent mini-tutorial. Do you have any suggestion of literature to further learn Mathematica? Amazing!

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar Maybe you would be interested in the two first links of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45958/86543) and also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/86543) and this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/86543)

Answer (score 4):

*One* way would be to use `Inner`:

```
Inner[Times,vector,{1,1,1},Tan[#2/#1]&]


(* {0.328928, 0.0877953, -1.11698, 0.163536, 8.47242, -1.30076, -0.876783, -0.445995, 

    3.10856, 13.781, -0.0637223} *)
```

To join the result to `vector`, creating a new column:

```
result=Join[vector,Transpose[{Inner[Times,vector,{1,1,1},Tan[#2/#1]&]}],2]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0.923193 & 0.293373 & 0.28368 & 0.328928 \\
 0.563943 & 0.0493849 & 0.29899 & 0.0877953 \\
 0.0540691 & 0.464139 & 0.238681 & -1.11698 \\
 0.965447 & 0.1565 & 0.083503 & 0.163536 \\
 0.139205 & 0.639633 & 0.73339 & 8.47242 \\
 0.291075 & 0.647993 & 0.45214 & -1.30076 \\
 0.157494 & 0.381412 & 0.516915 & -0.876783 \\
 0.15384 & 0.418765 & 0.603784 & -0.445995 \\
 0.682685 & 0.859883 & 0.08333 & 3.10856 \\
 0.523494 & 0.784382 & 0.919915 & 13.781 \\
 0.0527971 & 0.991843 & 0.757848 & -0.0637223 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

where:

```
vector = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {n, 0, 10}]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.923193 & 0.293373 & 0.28368 \\
 0.563943 & 0.0493849 & 0.29899 \\
 0.0540691 & 0.464139 & 0.238681 \\
 0.965447 & 0.1565 & 0.083503 \\
 0.139205 & 0.639633 & 0.73339 \\
 0.291075 & 0.647993 & 0.45214 \\
 0.157494 & 0.381412 & 0.516915 \\
 0.15384 & 0.418765 & 0.603784 \\
 0.682685 & 0.859883 & 0.08333 \\
 0.523494 & 0.784382 & 0.919915 \\
 0.0527971 & 0.991843 & 0.757848 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$