# Prevent interdependence of controls

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

My question is probably best illustrated with this small sample code:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn1-eqn2}, {x,-5,5}],
 {{eqn1,r-x,"y1="}},{{eqn2,E^-x,"y2="}},
 {r,-2,2}
]
```

I would like to be able to have the user input two equations which including a variable `r`, and then use the slider to manipulate this variable. The issue is that `Manipulate` changes `r` within the input field, and then doesn't update the graphs.

Is there a way of allowing the user to input an equation which contains one of `Manipulate`'s variables without having it change that variable within the input field?

Comment: I wonder, why did you gave the title "Prevent..." when you explicitly want to **have** interdependence?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Well, I guess it depends what you see as being interdependent. I want the variable `r` to be interdependent, but not the controls themselves, so that change one control won't affect the input field itself.  

So essentially, the variable `r` is dependent on all controls, but the controls shouldn't be interdependent of each other.

Comment: So you only want to retain `eqn1` as `r - x` in the `InputField` instead of e.g. `1-x` (if `r` is 1)? If I'm correct, than indeed my first example is the way to do it.

Comment: Yep, that's correct, and indeed your first answer achieved exactly what I was hoping. The rest of the answer is an interesting exploration of the way `Manipulate` behaves, but isn't strictly answering my question.

Comment: Then I will split my answer and move the irrelevant parts to a new thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The symbol `r` that is controlled by the slider is automatically localized so manually entering an expression containing (global) `r` does not work.

How about a simple replacement of `r -> rr` where `rr` is the `Manipulate`-d variable?

The undocumented option `Evaluated -> True` is used to retain individual line styles.<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121)</sup>

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn1 - eqn2} /. r -> rr, {x, -5, 5}, Evaluated -> True],
 {{eqn1, r - x, "y1="}},
 {{eqn2, E^-x, "y2="}},
 {{rr, -2, "r"}, -2, 2}]
```

**Edited**

Moved off-topic discussion on variable decoupling to [this new post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11213/89).

Comment: István, I edited your answer.  I included an explanation of the need for the replacement rule as well as an option to preserve the unique line styling.  I also found that the second form you showed did not work for me so I removed it; please add it back if you see fit.  I hope this edit is not stepping on your toes; instead my intent is to enhance this answer rather than posting a competing one.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard, no toestepping at all. I wanted to include some explanations but wasn't able to figure out, so I left it for a later rewriting. You were faster, as usually :) I'm still not sure I understand though: if `r` is local to the slider, how come it is updated in the `InputField`, and not in the body of the `Manipulate`? My second solution works consistently on my end (though I don't like it, would rather wrap the whole thing in `DynamicModule`)... are you using v6 or 7? What could cause this discrepancy of versions?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Nasser: Please check update and provide some insight if you could.

Comment: @Nasser: you are right in that this example is not useful for the OP, but the underlying problem is that the initial value definition in a `Manipulate` is not enough to trigger body updates. My example is a remedy for that.

Comment: It is also possible to force the re-evaluation of `x` in the minimal example by making it dynamic. So `Manipulate[{Dynamic[x], r}, {{x, r}}, {r, 0, 1}]` will see both values being changed. In the context of the initial question however, this is not that useful since the input field is also modified.

Comment: @Nasser I think you should post a separate question.  The issue here is that symbols are localized to `$CellContext` and parameters additionally with `$$`.  For example:  `Manipulate[Hold[r], {r, -2, 2}]`.  You probably should use a manually constructed object with `Dynamic` and `Control` rather than Manipulate if you don't want the automatic scoping.