# Control variable and body variable decoupling in Manipulate

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

This issue was raised as an offside problem in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11157/89). Consider the following example, that does not work as expected:

```
Manipulate[{x, r}, {{x, r}}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

Note that as `r` is manipulated the `InputField` of `x` is updated (as the initial value of `x` is set to be `r`) **but not the** `x` displayed as the body of the `Manipulate`. Interestingly, if `x` depends on `r` in a different way (endpoints of range instead of initial value) the example works as expected: whenever `r` is changed it changes both the displayed values of `x`:

```
Manipulate[{x, r}, {x, r, 1}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

It seems like that in `Manipulate` changing a variable (`r`) does not trigger a re-evaluation of the initial-value-dependent variable (`x`) displayed in the body though its value displayed in the control is updated correctly.

**I have no idea why the first example does not work the same way as the second does.** While it might be said that this is a feature, I would argue that the unexplained decoupling of the two representations of `x` (as body and control) is quite disturbing.

**Workarounds**

1. The re-evaluation can be triggered by making `x` dynamic:

   ```
   Manipulate[{Dynamic[x], r}, {{x, r}}, {r, 0, 1}]
   ```
2. Moving the definition of `x` out of the control-arguments to the body of the `Manipulate`:

   ```
   Manipulate[{x = r, r}, {r, 0, 1}]
   ```
3. Rewriting it in `DynamicModule`: it has an explicit function inside the `Dynamic` of `r` that sets `x` whenever `r` is modified:

   ```
   Panel@DynamicModule[{x, r = .5},
       x = r;
       Grid[{
             {"x", InputField[Dynamic[x]]},
             {"r", Slider[Dynamic[r, (r = #; x = #) &], {0, 1}]},
             {Panel[Dynamic@{x, r}], SpanFromLeft}
            }, Alignment -> Left]
       ]
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `InputForm` sheds some light:

```
Manipulate[{x, r}, {{x, r}}, {r, 0, 1}] // InputForm
(* Manipulate[{x, r}, {{x, r}},{r, 0, 1}] *)

Manipulate[{x, r}, {x, r, 1}, {r, 0, 1}] // InputForm
(* Manipulate[{x, r}, {x, Dynamic[r], 1}, {r, 0, 1}]*)
```

The desired behaviour of the first example can be achieve by this modification:

```
Manipulate[{x, r}, {x, r}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

Which has an input form of:

```
Manipulate[{x, r}, {x, r}, {r, 0, 1}] // InputForm
(* Manipulate[{x, r}, {x, Dynamic[r]}, {r, 0, 1}] *)
```

However `Manipulate` doesn't know how to render the control type, so therefore

```
Manipulate[{x, r}, {x, r, ControlType -> InputField}, {r, 0, 1}] // InputForm
(* Manipulate[{x, r}, {x, Dynamic[r], ControlType -> InputField}, {r, 0, 1}] *)
```

allows the first example to have similar behaviour to the second example.

**Edit**

In reply to the comment from @István Zachar this is my best guess as to *why* -- with the qualifier that I mostly use `DynamicModule` not `Manipulate` so am not an expert on its inner workings.

```
Manipulate[{x, r}, {{x, r}}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

is of the form `Manipulate[{x, r}, {{u, u_unit}}, {r, 0, 1}]`. It seems like an incomplete expression and the syntax colouring for `x` doesn't indicate localization. This is confirmed by `Manipulate[{x, r}, {{x, r, 1}}, {r, 0, 1}]` which is of the form `Manipulate[{x, r}, {{u, u_unit,u_label}}, {r, 0, 1}]` and renders as

[image]

So as written (i.e. `{{u, u_unit}}`) there is a value to display in the input field, `r`, but there is not a complete definition for `x`.

Comment: While this answer indeed sheds some light, it does not give an explanation why it is like that. It still does not answer the question, why does `x` in the `InputField` get's updated but not `x` in the body, if they are the same. Aren't they?

Comment: Agreed, no explanation, and the thing is that `Manipulate` _does_ know how to render the control type for `x` because it renders an input field which is correctly updated; and not only does it know how to render it, if you use the input field to change the value of `x`, then the _body_ also gets updated accordingly!  Looks like a bug to me.