# Problem with ParametricPlot of multiple Curves

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I have written a function `f[Ne,t,T]`, that gives back a **list** of results when  evaluated with numeric values of the variables `Ne`, `t` and `T`.

Now I want to make a `ParametricPlot` of the first element of the resulting list against another function `g[t,T]` for different values of the parameter `T`. So I try it for example like this:

```
TList={0,1,2};
ParametricPlot[ Table[ {Part[f[5,t,T],1] , g[t,T]} , {T,TList}] ,{t,0,10}]
```

Since I didn't use `Evaluate` inside `ParametricPlot`, all the curves have the same color. But if I do us `Evaluate` inside `ParametricPlot`,  for example like this:

```
TList={0,1,2};
ParametricPlot[ Evaluate@Table[ {Part[f[5,t,T],1] , g[t,T]} , {T,TList}] ,{t,0,10}]
```

then `Part` is acting too early, and `f[5,t,T]` is evaluated to 5 (which is of course the first part of the expression `f[5,t,T]`), but that's clearly not that what I want. I want the `Table` command to be evaluated, so that `ParametricPlot` can "see" the different curves, but I want the first part of `f[Ne,t,T]` to be taken **after** the function `f[5,t,T]` is evaluated for the actual value of `t`. So what can I do?

Comment: What is the definition of `f` and `g`?

Comment: The function f is a call to a Fortran program via MathLink and g is a complicated function i setted up in a pacage so i cant give the definitions here... But the point is, that f needs to be evaluated Before Part 1 is taken...

Comment: @user5373 You could provide arbitrary placeholder functions, just so people have somthing to test it with. I used `f[Ne_?NumericQ,t_?NumericQ,T_?NumericQ]:={Ne t T,0}` and `g[t_,T_]:=t Sin[T]` testing my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way around this is to use an Upvalue for `f` to indicate that you actually want to wait with the evaluation of `Part` until it doesn't have the head `f` anymore. I do this here by switching to `hPart` which I define such that it will evaluate back to `Part` for anything except expressions with head `f`:

```
 f /: Part[a_f, n_] := hPart[a, n]
 hPart[a : Except[_f], n_] := Part[a, n]
```

That way `Part[f[2,3,a],3]` evaluates to `hPart[f[2,3,a],3]` and when `a` takes a numerical value and `f` evaluates, `hPart` evaluates and gets the right part.

Comment: Yes, tanks alot!!! Taht works great!!

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension to jVincent's answer.

Using `UpValues` is not necessary.  You can also define your own function to use in place of `Part`.

```
f[x_, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := {x Cos[y - z], x + y + z}

g[y_, z_] := Sin[y + z] - z

TList = {0, 1, 2};

part[x : Except[_f], spec__] := Part[x, spec]

ParametricPlot[
  {part[f[5, t, #], 1], g[t, #]} & /@ TList,
  {t, 0, 10},
  Evaluated -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I use `Evaluated -> True` because it [correctly localizes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121) `t`.

If the output of your functions is always a list this function could be generally defined:

```
part[x_List, spec__] := Part[x, spec]
```