# Plotting a list along with its trend line

Tags: plotting, fitting

Say I have these data:

```
data = {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 7}};
```

I want to fit these data with a quadratic equation, like this:

```
Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
```

*Mathematica* then outputs $1.5 + 1.4x$. However, trying to plot this like this:

```
Plot[Fit[data, {1, x}, x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

Results in the errors

```
General::ivar: 0.00010214285714285715` is not a valid variable.
General::ivar: 0.00010214285714285715` is not a valid variable.
General::ivar: 0.10214295918367347` is not a valid variable.
General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

I tried copying the $1.5 + 1.4x$ directly into `Plot`, after which I saw that it did not actually say $1.5 + 1.4x$:

```
Plot[1.5000000000000009` + 1.3999999999999995` x, {x, 0, 5}]
```

So that's where the ` came from. Surely removing them manually is not the way to go. What went wrong?

Answer (score 8):

`Plot` has `Attributes` of `HoldAll`. This can be verified by:

```
Attributes@Plot
```

> `{HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}`

...from the second point under Details and Options in the [`Plot` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html):

> `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` and evaluates [the function] only after assigning specific numerical values to [the independent variable].

So in your example, we want to force `Plot` to evaluate the `Fit` function before attempting to create the graphics:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Fit[data, {1, x}, x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

and to combine with the data.

```
Show[{Plot[Evaluate@Fit[data, {1, x}, x], {x, 0, 5}], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, 2]]}]
```

or

```
Plot[Evaluate@Fit[data, {1, x}, x], {x, 0, 5}, Epilog -> {ColorData[1, 2], Point@data}]
```

[image]

As to your second point, when you copy the output of `Fit` and paste it into the front end, a real number approximation is shown based on `$MachinePrecision`.

Comment: [Using `Evaluated -> True` instead of `Evaluate` will localize `x`.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121) (+1)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `LinearModelFit` like this:

```
data={{1,3},{2,4},{3,6},{4,7}};
lmf=LinearModelFit[data,x,x];
p1=Plot[lmf[x],{x,0,5}];
p2=ListPlot[data,PlotStyle->{PointSize@Large,Red}];
Show[p1,p2]
```

To get:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could, of course, choose to use `FindFit[]` instead:

```
fitLine[x_] = a + b x /. FindFit[data, a + b x, {a, b}, x]

Plot[fitLine[x], {x, 0, 5}, Axes -> None,
     Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[6], Red], Point[data]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: points with best-fit line]

This works, since `FindFit[]` returns a list of replacement rules for the coefficients:

```
FindFit[data, a + b x, {a, b}, x]
   {a -> 1.5, b -> 1.4}
```

You can then use `ReplaceAll[]` (`/.`) to replace the coefficients in `a + b x` with the numerical values found by `FindFit[]`. (I used `Set[]` instead of `SetDelayed[]` so that the replacement is instantly done before the function `fitLine[]` is defined.)

Comment: +1, however IMHO you should use formal symbols or add `Block`, or at least reference these methods.

Comment: Hmm, maybe later...