# How to plot periodic function's graphic?

Tags: plotting, functions, faq

***How to plot periodic function's graphic?***

For example, $f(t) = t$ when $-5<t<5$ and $f(t+10) = f(t)$.

```
f[t] := If[-5 <= t <= 5, t, f[t + 10] = f[t]];
Plot[f[t], {t, -20, 20}]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Your syntax is off. Functions in Mathematica are defined by patterns, so it needs to be `f[t_]` on the left hand side. Also, I don't know why you expect Mathematica to understand `f[t+10]=f[t]` properly. It works if you define it like this: `f[t_] := If[-5 <= t <= 5, t, If[t > 0, f[t - 10], f[t + 10]]];`

Comment: [A related math.SE question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63456/63463#63463)

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57554/how-to-add-periodicity-to-condition/57625#57625

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What about this?

This defines a rather general function `myperiodic`that translate a normal function to periodic form, the second parameter `{val, min, max}` specify a periodic interval of your desired periodic function:

```
myperiodic[func_, {val_Symbol, min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ}] :=
    func /. (val :> Mod[val - min, max - min] + min)
```

Then you can use it to plot things:

```
Plot[myperiodic[t, {t, -5, 5}] // Evaluate, {t, -40, 40}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[myperiodic[t^2, {t, -3, 5}] // Evaluate, {t, -40, 40}]
```

[image]

---

## Extensions

We can extend this function in a couple of possibly useful ways.  It may be noted that if `t` has a global value the plots above will fail, because `Evaluate` breaks the scoping of `Plot`.  This could be remedied by using [the `Evaluated` option](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121) but it would be nice not to need either.  We can achieve that by holding arguments unevaluated using `HoldAll` and then holding at least the Symbol and expression unevaluated while making the substitution.  These methods come to mind:

- Adding `Unevaluated` and `HoldPattern` to the existing replacement
- leveraging the attributes of `Pattern` and `RuleDelayed` in an inverted rule form [(injector pattern)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121)
- Using `Function` which holds parameter name and body
- An undocumented syntax for `With` (`:=`) that does not evaluate substitution expressions

In code:

```
SetAttributes[{periodic1, periodic2, periodic3, periodic4}, HoldAll]

periodic1[expr_, {s_Symbol, min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ}] := 
  Unevaluated[expr] /. HoldPattern[s] :> Mod[s, max - min, min]

Quiet[
  periodic2[expr_, {s_Symbol, min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ}] := 
    Mod[s, max - min, min] /. s_ :> expr
]

periodic3[expr_, {s_Symbol, min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ}] := 
  Function[s, expr][Mod[s, max - min, min]]

periodic4[expr_, {s_Symbol, min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ}] := 
  With[{s := Mod[s, max - min, min]}, expr]
```

Testing indicates that the last method is the fastest:

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming @ Do[#[7 + t^2, {t, -5, 5}], {t, -40, 40, 0.001}] & /@
 {periodic1, periodic2, periodic3, periodic4}
```

> ```
> {0.35492, 0.382667, 0.237522, 0.235105}
> ```

Demonstration of use:

```
Plot[periodic4[7 + t^2, {t, -5, 5}], {t, -40, 40}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The next extension that can be valuable it to have periodic return a function rather than a bare expression.  While the functions above evaluate correctly internally in the presence of a global assignment to the declared Symbol the result evaluates with that global value and therefore cannot be reused.  Returning a function allows us to use it more generally such as mapping over a list of values, which can have advantage as I will show.

#### Proposal

```
SetAttributes[periodic, HoldAll]

periodic[expr_, {s_Symbol, min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ}] := 
  Join[s &, With[{s := Mod[s, max - min, min]}, expr &]]
```

(Note that `Join` works on any head.  `Function` acts to hold the parts of the final `Function` before it is assembled.)

Now:

```
periodic[7 + t^2, {t, -5, 5}]
```

> ```
> Function[t, 7 + Mod[t, 5 - -5, -5]^2]
> ```

```
Plot[periodic[7 + t^2, {t, -5, 5}][x], {x, -40, 40}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

(Note that `x` was used above for clarity but using `t` would not conflict.)

If the somewhat awkward from of `Function` returned is a concern know that it will be optimized by `Compile`, either manually or automatically:

```
Compile @@ periodic[7 + t^2, {t, -5, 5}]
```

> ```
> CompiledFunction[{t}, 7 + (Mod[t + 5, 10] - 5)^2, -CompiledCode-]
> ```

The function-generating form does not perform quite as well (as e.g. `periodic4`) when used naively:

```
Table[periodic[7 + t^2, {t, -5, 5}][t], {t, -40, 40, 0.001}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.3600206
> ```

However it allows for superior performance if applied optimally, using `Map`, which auto-compiles:

```
periodic[7 + t^2, {t, -5, 5}] /@ Range[-40, 40, 0.001] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0130007
> ```

As a final touch we can give our function proper syntax highlighting:

```
SyntaxInformation[periodic] =
 {"LocalVariables" -> {"Table", {2}}, "ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, {_, _, _}}};
```

[image]

– *Mr.Wizard*

Comment: ，I want to know why I cannot log in stackexchange of mathematica in China?

Comment: I have no trouble logging in this site in China. Are you Chinese? And if you want to chat, please go to the chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica

Comment: @mm.Jang I would like to attempt to refine your code.  Would you prefer that I edit your answer, or post one of my own?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Edit my answer would be nice :) Thanks.

Comment: Done.  I hope you like it.

Comment: This makes my function more robust and useful. And it teaches me a lot, thank you.

Comment: Note that `Mod[val - min, max - min] + min` is equivalent to the simpler `Mod[val, max - min, min]`.

Comment: @ShutaoTang In China, only some areas in "big" cities have access to facebook and/or youtube and/or google. So if you use facebook to log in, you might have some problems.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu,Yes, you're right:)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard    why it doesn't work if you put Pi in the range of t? for example `Plot[myperiodic[Exp[2*t], {t, -Pi, Pi}] // Evaluate, {t, -20, 20}]` ?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Good catch.  Every appearance of `NumberQ` should be `NumericQ`; I copied the first form in writing my extension without considering the implication of that.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Two years late but I applied your simplification.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 10):

another way to define a periodic function

```
Clear[f];
f[t_ /; -5 <= t < 5 ] := t
f[t_ /; t >= 5] := f[t - 10];
f[t_ /; t < -5] := f[t + 10];
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a pretty straightforward alternative for defining a periodic function:

```
 f[t_] := Which[-5 < t <= 5, t^2, t < -5, f[t + 10], t > 5, f[t - 10]]

 Plot[f[t], {t, -30, 30}]
```

[image]

Or, equivalently (and somewhat more concisely)

```
 g[t_] := If[Abs[t] < 5, t^2, g[t - Sign[t] 10]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Using built in functions: `SawtoothWave` , `TriangleWave`, and `SquareWave`:

```
Plot[10 SawtoothWave[(x - 5)/10] - 5, {x, -20, 20}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

```
Plot[SawtoothWave[x]^2, {x, -2, 2}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

```
Plot[1 - TriangleWave[x/(4 \[Pi])]^2, {x, -5 \[Pi], 5 \[Pi]}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[-5 \[Pi], 5 \[Pi], \[Pi]], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hey dude I know this is a year late but I have another option that people might be interested in :) You can also use the modulus to create a periodic waveform similar to previous comments but this is the "uncompressed" version :)!

```
f[t_] := t;
periodicf[t_] := f[Mod[t, 10] - 5];
Plot[periodicf[t], {t, -100, 100}]
```

[image: Periodic Waveform]

You'll notice that I've shifted the t value because you'd like it to start from a non-zero t value but then that results in a shift in the graph. To fix that we can use:

```
f[t_] := t;
periodicf[t_] := f[Mod[t+5, 10] - 5];
Plot[periodicf[t], {t, -100, 100}]
```

[image: Shifted Periodic Waveform]

So in general if you have a fuction, f[t], and you want to make it periodic, periodicf[t], between the domain [minTime, maxTime] then you can use this structure:

```
f[t_] := t; (* Or any function of time that you want *)
periodicf[t_] := f[Mod[t - minTime, maxTime-minTime] + minTime];
Plot[periodicf[t], {t, -100, 100}]
```

Let's test it for the same thing but from -1 < t < 3:

```
f[t_] := t;
minTime = -1;
maxTime = 3;
periodicf[t_] := f[Mod[t - minTime, maxTime - minTime] + minTime];
Plot[periodicf[t], {t, -100, 100}]
```

[image: Testing the Periodic Waveform Structure]

I'd also like to mention that I know that I read this somewhere else on the internet and remembered it because it's such a great trick but I can't remember where I read it :/! So please don't give me full credit for this :)!

Comment: This answer seems closely related to the answer by mm.Jang.

Comment: I agree with @bbgodfrey, this is an almost duplicate answer - I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: It's also in the link I gave (or at least in a slightly different form).

Comment: If you want to delete it then you can but why I put it here is because it shows what mm.Jang is actually doing in less complicated syntax. Instead of just copying code because it works I thought it might be useful to understand why it works? That's why it's "uncompressed" :) But if you guys rate I should remove it I will :'(