# How to add periodicity to condition?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Is it possible to set the following function `f[a]`, where `a` can be any real number?

> $$
>  f(\alpha) =
>   \begin{cases}
>    1 & \text{if } 2\pi n < \alpha < \pi (2n+1)  \\
>    2 & \text{if } \pi (2n+1) \le \alpha \le 2\pi (n+1)
>   \end{cases}, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}\
> $$

The issue here is `n` which I want to be substituted consecutively by an integer in order to produce propriate continuous conditions. I guess, it is not the case where `Assumptions` should be used as my attempt underneath doesn't work.

```
f[a_] := \[Piecewise] {
   {1, 2 \[Pi]n < a && a < \[Pi] (2 n + 1)},
   {2, \[Pi] (2 n + 1) <= a && a <= 2 \[Pi] (n + 1)}
  }, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to make your function periodic:

```
f[t_] := Which[0 <= t < Pi, 1, Pi <= t < 2 Pi, 2, t < 0, f[t + 2 Pi],  t > 2 Pi, f[t - 2 Pi]]
```

For example:

```
Plot[f[t], {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

This method works well for any function you care to use (not just square waves). For instance, f[t] can be linear in one half and quadratic in the second half:

```
f[t_] := Which[0 <= t < Pi, t, Pi <= t < 2 Pi, t^2, t < 0, f[t + 2 Pi], t > 2 Pi, f[t - 2 Pi]];
Plot[f[t], {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the built-in function `SquareWave`:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := SquareWave[{2, 1}, x/(2 Pi)];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10 Pi}, Ticks -> {Pi Range[10], Automatic},
    ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {0, 3}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

**Update:** another alternative: Use `ListInterpolation` with options `InterpolationOrder->0` and `PeriodicInterpolation -> True`

```
ClearAll[f2];
f2[x_] := ListInterpolation[{2, 1, 2}, {{0, 2 Pi}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
            PeriodicInterpolation -> True][x];
Plot[f2[x], {x, 0, 10 Pi}, Ticks -> {Pi Range[10], Automatic}, 
     Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> {0, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Mod` with a non-integer second argument:

```
f[a_] := Ceiling[Mod[a, 2 \[Pi]]/\[Pi]]
```

To generalize you can make a `Periodic` operator as follows:

```
Periodic[T_, offset_: 0][f_] := f@*((Mod[#, T] - offset) &)
f2pi = Periodic[2 \[Pi]][Ceiling[#/\[Pi]] &]
f3pi = Periodic[3 \[Pi], 0.1][Ceiling[#/\[Pi]] &]
quadratic[x_] := (x/\[Pi])^2;
parabola = Periodic[2 \[Pi], \[Pi]][quadratic]
```

We offset `f3pi` so that the lines will show up in the plot:

```
Plot[{f2pi[x], f3pi[x], parabola[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> None]
```

gives something akin to

[image: plot]

To get bill s' piecewise function, you can simply do:

```
bills[t_]:=bills[t_] := Which[t < \[Pi], t, True, t^2]

Plot[Periodic[2\[Pi]][bills][t], {t,-10,10}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method that uses [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitStep.html) and `Sin` to generate the square wave. `Sin` produces the periodicity and `UnitStep` maps the sinusoid into a square-wave. This method will be faster than `Which`.

```
f[x_] := 1 + UnitStep[Sin[x + Pi]]
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> None, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: sq-wave]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of [`Floor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Floor.html),

> `Floor[x, a]` gives the greatest multiple of `a` less than or equal to `x`

and [`Mod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod.html),

> `Mod[m, n]` gives the remainder on division of `m` by `n`

to get

```
f[x_] := 1 + Floor[Mod[x, 2 π]/π]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]