# Expressing $f(x)=-x \;\;\; -2\leq x \leq 0\\f(x)=x \;\;\; 0< x \leq 2\\f(x+4)=f(x)$ on Mathematica?

Tags: piecewise

Can we express functions such as:

$$f(x)=-x \quad -2\leq x \leq 0\\f(x)=x \quad 0< x \leq 2\\f(x+4)=f(x)$$

On Mathematica? I tried something with piecewise functions but it didn't work. Namely, I couldn't make the last condition. I tried:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{-x, -2 <= x <= 0 }, {x, 0 < x <= 2 }}]
f[x_ + 4] := f[x]
```

Comment: Note that in this particular case and due to the form of the piecewise function, you can use the more straightforward f[x_]:=Abs[x]

Comment: Try `f[x_]:= f[Mod[x,4,-2]]`

Comment: See, for example, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57625/7936 and other answers to that question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    f[x_] := Abs[TriangleWave[x/8]];
Plot[f[x], {x, -8, 8}]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: I think you need to scale (y) by 2: `2 Abs@TriangleWave[x/8]` (+1)

Comment: @ Michael E2 You are right

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
Clear[f]
```

To avoid an attempt at infinite recursion, the argument of `f` should be restricted to numeric values.

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{
   {-x, -2 <= x <= 0},
   {x, 0 < x <= 2},
   {f[x - 4], x > 2},
   {f[x + 4], x < -2}}]

f /@ {-17.25, -1.5, 1.75, 16.5}

(* {1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 0.5} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
g[t_] := If[Abs[t] < 2, Abs[t], g[t - 4 Sign[t]]]
```

which produces the same plot as Alexei's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Periodic` operator I wrote [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57625/7936)

```
Periodic[T_, offset_ : 0][f_] := f@*((Mod[#, T] - offset) &)
```

we can say

```
f = Periodic[4,2][Abs]
```

to get the function of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
f = Interpolation[{{-2, 2}, {0, 0}, {2, 2}},
 InterpolationOrder -> 1, PeriodicInterpolation -> True];
Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 6}]
```

[image]