# A piecewise function with way too many pieces

Tags: fitting, fourier-analysis, piecewise

I'm currently calculating a periodic square wave current function to feed into a particle accelerator. It's a square wave that ramps up to a certain frequency and then drops back to the base frequency and starts all over.

Between *Mathematica* and an iterative python script, I managed to get a list of 308 times (between t=0 and t=8.4*10^-6) when the voltage needs to flip from high to low, or the reverse.

Basically, I have a giant CSV from the python script that I have read into *Mathematica* as a list of values. At t=0, the voltage will be at 5000, and it should flip between 5000 and 0 at each time value in the list.

Is there a better way than using Python to construct a mile-long function using Piecewise that lists all the intervals where it should be on high voltage? Is there a way to make it periodic, so that repeats on modulo (2*Last[b] - Part[b,-2])?

Finally, is there a way to have *Mathematica* try to calculate the Fourier transform of this ugly piecewise function so that I can more easily port it into MATLAB for use with the function generator?

[Python script generating values](http://pastebin.com/FyrNBGKz)

Somewhat terrible drawing of this graph (black is my values, red line is where it should become periodic):

[image: my square wave]

How I'm importing:

```
b = Import["C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\calculations\\swaptimes.txt", 
  "List"]
```

Comment: You know that `SquareWave[]` is built-in?

Comment: SquareWave is for constant period- my function's period changes. Read the question.

Comment: Can you provide a small list and expected output to get the picture of what you are after?

Comment: How does the frequency ramp up? Can it be described in a function? If so then use that function as an argument to SquareWave mentioned by @J.M.isback.

Comment: @Matariki Right now, I'm generating the list of when to change the voltage with the script in the pastebin. I don't think this could be put into a function, but if you have an idea, hit me. Every number that the function prints is a time that the voltage would need to change.

http://pastebin.com/FyrNBGKz

Comment: @garej I drew you a picture! horizontal axis is time, vertical is voltage. The black marks are the values I generated in my list, and the red line is where the function would ideally repeat itself from zero. 

https://imgur.com/72IZ54c

Comment: Consider editing your post to include the picture in your last comment, as well as the pastebin link to your data.

Comment: @J.M.isback. Just did- does it make better sense now?

Comment: I see, something like a chirp, but for a square wave, and made periodic. Matariki's suggestion to modify the argument of `SquareWave[]` to vary the spacing is good. To make the thing periodic, you might want to see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32689).

Comment: I think I got the periodicity part, but how would I modify SquareWave[] to make this work? I just don't see how the data could be expressed as a function.

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
 times = Join[{0}, Sort@RandomReal[100, {20}], {100}];
 f = Interpolation[
   MapIndexed[ {#, 5000 Boole@EvenQ[First@#2]} &, times], 
          InterpolationOrder -> 0];
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

now make periodic: (edit revised so its scaled he same as your data I think)

```
 tper=8.4*10^-6;
 times = Join[{0}, Select[Accumulate@
           Sort@RandomReal[{.01, .4} tper, {100}], # < tper &], {tper}];
 f = Interpolation[
      MapIndexed[{#, 5000 Boole@EvenQ[First@#2]} &, times], 
            InterpolationOrder -> 0];
 g[x_] := f[Mod[x, tper ]]
Plot[g[x], {x, -tper , 2 tper }, PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

I do not readily see a nice way to compute a `FourierTransform` of this: I'd suggest you might break that out as a new question.

Comment: I'm not really sure how your code works, but I subbed in my list for times, and got the following error: `InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {0.00204286} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."` I am probably making a mistake.

Comment: Update: just realized that your (working) code gives this error as well. However, when I run it with my values, it plots nothing anyway.

Comment: Be sure to include zero in your list. See my edit, that's what the `Join[{0}..` does.

Comment: Mine looks, well, constant at 5000.