# Periodic boundary condition trick

Tags: graphics, manipulate, output, display, periodic-function

I'm plotting a curve on a compact space which is having periodic boundaries on the left and right parts.  Currently, the code I'm using is working great, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler and more natural way of achieving this, instead of using an "hack".  Here's a MWE code showing the case :

```
curves[a_, b_] := ParametricPlot[{ (* Three duplicates of the same curve, to simulate the periodic boundaries : *)
        {a + ArcSin[Sin[b]Sin[s]], s},
        {a - Pi + ArcSin[Sin[b]Sin[s]], s},
        {a + Pi + ArcSin[Sin[b]Sin[s]], s}
    },
    {s, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.80]],
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, 0 <= x <= Pi]
]

Manipulate[
    Show[
        curves[a Pi, b Pi],
        PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}},
        PlotRangeClipping -> True,
        PlotRangePadding -> None,
        AspectRatio -> 1,
        Frame -> True, Axes -> True,
        ImageSize -> 500
    ],
    {{a, 0, "x"}, 0, 1, 0.01},
    {{b, 0, "y"}, -0.5, 0.5, 0.01}
]
```

As you can see in the definition of the `curves[a_, b_]` function, I'm using three times the same curve, translated by $\pi$ and $-\pi$ on the horizontal axis, to simulate the periodic boundaries.  I feel a bit unconfortable with this trick (it's hard to say why).

So is there another way of achieving the result, something simpler or more "natural" for ***Mathematica*** ?  Or mathematically more "correct", using one curve definition instead ?

Comment: what about Mod? I cannot get it to work though, but maybe this gets you started `curves[a_, b_] := 
 ParametricPlot[{{Mod[\[Pi]/
       2 (a + ArcSin[Sin[b] Sin[s]]), \[Pi]], 
    Mod[\[Pi]/2 + s, \[Pi]] - \[Pi]/2}}, {s, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.80]], 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, 0 <= x <= Pi]]` need to run now.

Comment: Have you seen this... http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32689/1783

Comment: @tsuresuregusa, your suggestion almost works, but it adds a straight horizontal and vertical lines that shouldn't be there.

Comment: there is an answer for that here in the site but didn't have time to implement it, maybe you can figure it out.