# Plot a Repeating Discontinuous Function over 'n' Periods

Tags: plotting

[image]

How would I get Mathematica to plot the above discontinuous function over any number of periods (or perhaps over any given range)?

i.e. $0 \ to \ 6\pi$, or $-2\pi \ to \ 10\pi$

I have seen a few ways to plot continuous functions, but not discontinuous.
I regret that I am also very new to the program! :)

For example: [How to plot periodic function's graphic?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32689/how-to-plot-periodic-functions-graphic)
This question was answered, but I cannot see how I can create the plot of a discontinuous function with the explanations provided there.

I did try this code (any many others, inspired by various other Stack Exchange answers), but I didn't get any result on my plot:

```
f[t_ /;  0 <= t < Pi] := 3;
f[t_ /; Pi <= t < 2 Pi] := 0;
f[t_ /; t >=  2 Pi] := f[t + 2 Pi];
f[t_ /; t < 0] := f[t - 2 Pi];
Plot[t[{1, 5}], {t, -2 Pi, 4 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Look at [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html), [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) and [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html). Also, please show some effort of your own.

Comment: Thankyou, I have been over those resources - and many others - but I have been unsuccessful. I feel I'm approaching the problem the wrong way.  
f[t_ /;  0 <= t < Pi] := 3;
f[t_ /; Pi <= t < 2 Pi] := 0;
f[t_ /; t >=  2 Pi] := f[t + 2 Pi];
f[t_ /; t < 0] := f[t - 2 Pi];
Plot[t[{1, 5}], {t, -2 Pi, 4 Pi}]

Comment: If the linked thread does not address your concerns, please edit your post to explain why so that it can be reopened.

Comment: has been closed, hence in comments `fun = Piecewise[{{3, Mod[x, 2 \[Pi]] < \[Pi]}, {0, 
    Mod[x, 2 \[Pi]] >= \[Pi]}}]` and `Plot[fun, {x, -2 \[Pi], 10 \[Pi]}]`

Comment: @J.M. I believe there are some key differences between the function plotted within the link you posted, and the discontinuous periodic function which is the subject of my question. I have successfully plotted a number of continuous functions - having taken advice from the linked thread - but have not had similar success with this one :)

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 Thankyou for your input! :)  
However that code produces a continuous function. I need to plot a discontinuous function (with no vertical lines)

Comment: hmm... I do not get vertical lines with this code..

Comment: oh, perhaps I have some different configuration? I am now trying to use Exclusions to remove them, also.

Comment: I use the osx 11.0.1.0 version right now

Comment: same on linux 11.1.1.0

Comment: maybe use `Plot[fun, {x, -2 \[Pi], 10 \[Pi]}, Exclusions -> True]`?

Comment: That has worked! I am on Windows - maybe that's it? Thankyou for your help :)

Comment: Try this: `fsection[t_] := Piecewise[{{3, 0 <= t < π}, {0, π <= t < 2 π}}, 0]; f[t_] := fsection[Mod[t, 2 π]]; Plot[f[t], {t, -4 π, 4 π}]`. This uses the same technique in the first answer of the linked question.

Comment: @J.M. Thankyou for your input. I tried what you have suggested but was returned `$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.` and a single period of the function, from 0 to 2pi, which was not discontinuous.

Comment: In that case, run `Remove[f, fsection]` and try that snippet again. Add `Exclusions -> {Sin[t] == 0}` if the vertical lines bother you.