# Combine `EvenQ` and `Clip` to create a series of pulses

Tags: functions, piecewise

I have a function that produces a single impulse spanning the range `[-1,1]`:

```
func1 = Cos[Pi*(Clip[x]/2)]^2
```

[image]

I want to create a second function that produces a series of such pulses, with each pulse centred on an instance of `EvenQ[x/3]=True`. It feels like it should be simple, but I can't figure it out. This is what I tried:

```
eventest = If[EvenQ[x/3] = True, 1, 0]; 
func2 = eventest*func1; 
Plot[func2, {x, 0, 20}]
```

...but as you can see, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @kglr, sadly this doesn't seem to work. it produces an inverted square wave in the range `[-1,1]` and nothing else. I'm after a series of pulses like the one I have now added to the original post, with each pulse centred on an instance of `x/3` is even.

Comment: thank you @Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the method from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32692) (see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/63463) as well):

```
pulse[x_] := Cos[π Clip[Mod[x, 6, -3]]/2]^2
```

Comment: (will add a plot when I am not using *gedanken Mathematica*)

Comment: Thanks @J.M. - this works, so will mark as answered; but I do wonder if there is a more general version that would work with more general sequences. For example, what if I wanted a sequence that gave pulses at all `x` that satisfy `TrueQ[truetest]` for some arbitrary test on `x`? Just trying to learn how to drive the machine better!

Comment: I like the idea of *gedanken Mathematica*, BTW! Hopefully you'll get the machine back soon! :-)

Comment: `Boole[]` (i.e. the Iverson bracket) is a useful tool for constructing general conditional functions; but, constructing the right conditions to put in it is as much art as science.

Comment: Interesting (and again thank you). I just tried `Plot[Boole[OddQ[x]]*Cos[Pi*(Clip[x]/2)]^2, {x, -5, 5}]`, but it just gives a flat-line zero... This could be tricky!

Comment: In that specific case, `Boole[OddQ[x]]` will indeed be equal to $1$ for odd integer `x` and $0$ otherwise. But,  the factor `Cos[π Clip[x]/2]^2`is $0$ almost everywhere (why?), so you need to modify that, too.

Comment: OK, I'm not thinking the way MMA wants me to think! The factor `Cos[π Clip[x]/2]^2` is centred on `x=0`. But why? I want it to be centred on whatever value of `x` the function takes. I'd understand if it was `Cos[π Clip[0]/2]^2` but it isn't...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84747/discussion-between-richard-burke-ward-and-j-m-is-computer-less).

Comment: I think that whole line of thought should be a new question; it would certainly be difficult to discuss in comments properly. ;)

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Plot[Boole[Or @@ (Divisible[{Floor[x + 1], Ceiling[x - 1]}, 6])] 
  Cos[Pi x / 2]^2, {x, -15, 15}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Also

```
Plot[Boole[And @@ EvenQ[Quotient[Through[{Floor, Ceiling}[x + 1]], 3]]] 
 Cos[Pi x/2]^2, {x, -15, 15}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Maybe change to `EvenQ[Round[x/3]]`?