# Combine single pulse with Boolean test, and integrate series

Tags: function-construction, conditional, boolean-computation

**I have edited this to include integration:**

This is a more general case of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184337/combine-evenq-and-clip-to-create-a-series-of-pulses).

I want to create a function that gives the integral of a series of single pulses of the form `Cos[Pi*(x/2)]^2` for all values of `x` that satisfy some Boolean test.

For example, say I wanted to create a curve that summed pulses for all instances of `x` on the Fibonacci sequence. Manually, I would do something like

```
Plot[{With[{n = 1}, Cos[Pi*(Clip[x - n]/2)]^2] + 
With[{n = 2}, Cos[Pi*(Clip[x - n]/2)]^2] + 
With[{n = 3}, Cos[Pi*(Clip[x - n]/2)]^2] + 
With[{n = 5}, Cos[Pi*(Clip[x - n]/2)]^2] + 
With[{n = 8}, Cos[Pi*(Clip[x - n]/2)]^2] + 
With[{n = 13}, Cos[Pi*(Clip[x - n]/2)]^2]}, {x, 0, 15}]
```

[image]

Integrating (how?) would create a continuous curve.

That's just an example. I want a function in the form `Integral[booleantest*pulse,x]` that gives the cumulative area under a series of this style of pulse, where each pulse is centred on *any* Boolean test on integer values of `x`.

So it seems to me that my question has three parts:

1. How do I create a function `pulse` that gives this pulse-form for all integer `x`? Clearly using `With[{n=...,]` isn't going to work. It requires me to manually specify all instances of `pulse`.
2. In principle, it's easy enough to create a Boolean test: `booleantest=Boole[EvenQ[x/3]]`, `booleantest=Boole[PrimeQ[x]]`, etc.

   So, how do I multiply the two together? `booleantest*pulse` should yield `pulse` for all instances of `booleantest=1`, and `0` else. But it doesn't work. For example: `pulse = Cos[Pi*(Clip[x - n]/2)]^2;booleantest = Boole[EvenQ[n/3]];Plot[pulse*booleantest, {n, 0, 15}]`

[image]

3. How do I create the integral?

I'm clearly doing lots of things wrong... So, sticking to the idea of `pulse*booleantest` (if possible), how do I do this?

**UPDATE**

Many thanks to @kglrfor the answer below. I have now tried to expand this to a more *general* Boolean choice, as per original post. I'm ashamed to say that I can't figure out how do it. @kglr, your suggestion works great for the Fibonacci sequence. But how would it work for, for example, with `EvenQ[x/n]=True`? Or 'FreeQ[{x},n]`? Or *any* of a host of other 'filters' of this general`Q` nature? It's the *general* approach that I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** A function that takes an arbitrary list of integers as the second argument:

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[x_?NumericQ, m : {__Integer}] := Total[Cos[Pi*(Clip[x - #]/2)]^2 & /@ m]
Grid[Partition[Plot[f2[x, #], {x, -1 + Min@#, 1 + Max@#}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> Style["m = " <> ToString[#], 16]] & /@ 
  {Fibonacci[Range@7], Select[Range[-5, 5], EvenQ], 
   Select[Range[-5, 5], OddQ], Select[Range[-15, 15], Divisible[#, 6] &], 
   {-11, -10, -9, -2,  1,  5, 6}, RandomSample[Range[-15, 15], 6]}, 3], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1[x_?NumericQ, n_Integer] := Total[Cos[Pi*(Clip[x - #]/2)]^2 & /@ Fibonacci[Range[n]]]
Grid[Partition[Plot[f1[x, #] , {x, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#], 
     PlotLabel -> Style["n = " <> ToString[#], 16], 
     PlotRange -> {0, 2}, ImageSize -> 200] & /@ Range[9], 3], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[f1[x, #] & /@ Range[9]], {x, 0, 20}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 2}, PlotLegends -> Range[9], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[x_?NumericQ, n_Integer] := NIntegrate[f1[s, n], {s, 0, x}]
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, f2[x, 7]}, {x, 0, 15, 1/100}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks @kglr :-)

Comment: Hi all (especially @kglr). Please see clarification in my edit to the original post above. The solution offered works for the Fibonacci series, but not in a more general context... So, I'm very grateful but would also appreciate further input.

Comment: Many thanks for the updated answer. Perfect!