# Weird behavior to plot a set of functions

Tags: plotting

I have this code, totally functional

```
$Assumptions = h > 0; 
p4[x_, h_] := x^4/24 + h*x^3/9 + h^2*x^2/12 - h^4/72; 
q4[x_, h_] := x^4/24 - h*x^3/9 + h^2*x^2/12 - h^4/72
Flatten@Table[{D[p4[x, 3], {x, n}], D[q4[x, 3], {x, n}]}, {n, 0, 3}]
```

But when I try to plot all these functions together I try to use the code

```
Plot[Flatten@Table[{D[p4[x, 3], {x, n}], D[q4[x, 3], {x, n}]}, {n, 0, 3}], {x, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

for some reason it doesnt work. Probably this is a silly mistake but I cant see how to solve it. Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use `Evaluate` inside the plot.
`Plot[Evaluate@
  Flatten@Table[{D[p4[x, 3], {x, n}], D[q4[x, 3], {x, n}]}, {n, 0, 
     3}], {x, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: Another option that works: `Plot[#, {x, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"] & @ 
 Flatten@Table[{D[p4[x, 3], {x, n}], D[q4[x, 3], {x, n}]}, {n, 0, 3}]`.  Unfortunately my [previously preferred form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121) `Evaluated -> True` doesn't work well with legends.