# Plot, HoldAll and the color problem

Tags: plotting, hold

I have a similar problem as posted in [Difference in Plot when using Evaluate vs when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/difference-in-plot-when-using-evaluate-vs-when-not-using-evaluate), however due to a numerical evaluation I cannot use `Evaluated->True` as a `Plot[]` option. Her a small example which gives errors:

```
f[y_, a_] := NIntegrate[y^2 + x, {x, 0, a}];
Plot[Table[f[y, a], {a, 1, 3}], {y, 0, 3}, Evaluated -> True]
```

The desired output should be equal to

```
Plot[{f[y, 1],f[y, 2],f[y, 3]}, {y, 0, 3}, Evaluated -> True]
```

How can I fix this example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the following works, but generates warning messages.

```
f[y_, a_] := NIntegrate[y^2 + x, {x, 0, a}];
Plot[Table[f[y, a], {a, 1, 3}], {y, 0, 3}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

The issue is that `Plot` (which usually holds it's first argument until specific values of $x$ are plugged in) tries to evaluate the first argument symbolically (due to the `Evaluated` option) and that causes an error since the numerical integral fails with symbolic arguments.  The standard way to get around this is to ensure that `f` does not evaluate until numerical values are plugged in, as follows:

```
Clear[f];
f[y_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[y^2 + x, {x, 0, a}];
Plot[Table[f[y, a], {a, 1, 3}], {y, 0, 3}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

I guess I'm assuming that you know the integral can be evaluated in closed form using `Integrate` and this is all just an example?