# How do I define a function that, when given a list of parameters, plots a family of functions?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, function-construction

So far I've got this:

```
draw[a_, b_] := Plot[{f[a, b[[1]], x], f[a, b[[2]], x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

The function `draw` will be used like this:

```
draw[10, {4, 7}]
```

The example is written for the case with two elements in the list that is the second argument. How do I do it when the second argument is a list with any number of elements?

Comment: It would help us to help you if you edited your question to include an example of kind of function you would give for `f`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Map:

```
draw[a_, b_] := Plot[Evaluate[f[a, #, x] & /@ b], {x, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: +1 (see also [this frequently asked question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/245))