# Plotting list-valued interpolating function

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I have an interpolation function which returns a list, e.g.:

```
f=Interpolation[{{1,{1,2,3}},{2,{4,5,6}}}];
```

When I try to plot it, I get single-colored curves.

```
Plot[f[x],{x,1,2}]
```

[image: result]

I'd like to make it use normal default different colors like here:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[2x+i,{i,0,2}],{x,1,2}]
```

[image]

But using `Evaluate` doesn't help in the first case as it does in the second. How can I get the colors for interpolation function?

Comment: Related: [(1731)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121)

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but while the answers to the related questions do explain the problem, it doesn't seem like they provide a solution to the specific problem of plotting multi-dimensional interpolating functions.