# Why don't rules applied inside ContourPlot3D work?

Tags: plotting

The output of the following code is the same as the input.

```
waals = (P + a/V^2) (V - b) == R T;

ContourPlot3D[waals /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, R -> 1},
 {P, 0, 100}, {V, 0, 100}, {T, 0, 100}]
```

But

```
ContourPlot3D[(P + 1/V^2) (-1 + V) == T,
 {P, 0, 100}, {V, 0, 100}, {T, 0, 100}]
```

works fine.

What's wrong? Do I have to specify all the parameters in the equation?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]You need to evaluate it before Plot to get placements done.

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Evaluate[waals /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, R -> 1}], {P, 0, 100}, {V, 0, 
  100}, {T, 0, 100}]
```

As suggested by @rcollyer, `ContourPlot3d` has HoldAll attribute, which can be seen as ,`Attributes[ContourPlot3D]` `(*{HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}*)`

Comment: The more complete answer is it has the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute.