# Does ContourPlot3D leak assignments inside Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, bugs

*Update 5 Aug 2015 --* [Karsten 7.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18476/karsten-7) found a minimal example of leaking not involving `Manipulate`, so the role of `Manipulate` seems more obscure. See notes 2 and 3 below.

The question, [Why don't rules applied inside ContourPlot3D work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30112/why-dont-rules-applied-inside-contourplot3d-work), suggests using `Evaluate` when the equation in `ContourPlot3D` involves `ReplaceAll`.  But in that case, `ReplaceAll` was the head of the first argument and `ContourPlot3D` returned unevaluated. Both these forms, with or without `Evaluate` work fine.

```
(* Evaluate: works *)
Clear[f, x, y, z];
f = x^3 + x z^2 - 3 x^2 + y^2 + 2 z^2;
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[
  f == (f + level /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> {2, 0, 0}]) // Evaluate,
  {x, 1, 3}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> {f, {x, y, z}}],
 {{level, 0.}, -1., 1.}]

(* no Evaluate, level init. 0.1: works *)
Clear[f, x, y, z];
f = x^3 + x z^2 - 3 x^2 + y^2 + 2 z^2;
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[f == (f + level /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> {2, 0, 0}]),
  {x, 1, 3}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> {f, {x, y, z}}],
 {{level, 0.1}, -1., 1.}]
```

They produce, after setting `level` to `0.1` in the first case, this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But if I do not use `Evaluate` and the variable `level` is initialized to `0.` instead of `0.1`, **the global variables `x`, `y`, and `z` are assigned values.**  The values are the coordinates of the far corner of the plot domain.  This remains through even if the ranges for `x`, `y`, or `z` are changed.  Another significant difference is that the plot disappears when the control is active, which does not happen in the other versions.

```
(* no Evaluate, level init. 0.: 
   {x,y,z} set, control active -> no plot, inactive -> green plot *)
Clear[f, x, y, z];
f = x^3 + x z^2 - 3 x^2 + y^2 + 2 z^2;
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[f == (f + level /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> {2, 0, 0}]),
  {x, 1, 3}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> {f, {x, y, z}}],
 {{level, 0.}, -1., 1.}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Check `x`, `y`, `z`:

```
{x, y, z}
(*  {3., 1., 1.}  *)
```

Why does this happen? I can see how to avoid it. Is there are reason one should expect the values of `x` etc. to leak out, or is it a bug?

Notes:

1. I've tested it on V10.2 and V9.0.1, OSX. Both versions give similar results (the coloring is different, of course).
2. [Karsten 7.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18476/karsten-7) points out that the symptom of leaking occurs with just `ContourPlot3D[1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 3}]`. However, the leaking does not occur in V9 for this form; instead a error is produced ("`Rest::norest`: Cannot take the rest of expression `{}` with length zero.")
3. The `ContourPlot3D` commands above when outside of `Manipulate` do not leak assignment. (I used `With[{level = 0.}, ContourPlot3D[...]]`.) If `x`, `y`, and `z` all have a value, then I get a green plot, unless `Evaluate` is used, but still no leaking.
4. The green color is suggestive (of three contours being plotted).  But I don't see why three contours should be expected.  Perhaps it's because three contours are the default.  As a hint, though, I find it obscure.
5. For the purposes of this question, I wish to ignore what happens when you substitute a minus for `Equal`, unless it explains what happens in this case. (I think there is a connection, but the cases to keep straight might get unmanageable.)

Comment: The `(* no Evaluate, level init. 0.1: works *)` example behaves like your last code block after changing level to `0.` or some value close to `0.` using the `Slider` or the Step Backward button of the `Manipulator`, but not when using the `InputField` or a `Label`.

Comment: @Karsten7. Oh! You're right.  (I thought I checked that, but apparently got lost in the ramification of cases.)  Thanks.

Comment: Global values of `{x, y, z}` get `Set` in all three examples, if `f` is undefined.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D` does even leak outside of `Manipulate`. For example: `ContourPlot3D[1, {x, 1, 3}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> {f, {x, y, z}}]`.

Comment: You might also try ``ContourPlot3D; System`ProtoPlotDump`iContourPlot3D[1, {x, 1, 
  3}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> {f, {x, y, z}}]``.

Comment: Or ``Visualization`Core`ContourPlot3D[1, {x, 1, 3}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
  PlotLabel -> {f, {x, y, z}}]``.

Comment: @Karsten7. Thanks again. `ContourPlot3D[1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 3}]` is a good minimal example. (Not too surprising that the actual bug lies inside the internal plotter.)