# Fitting one function to another

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I'd like to see how close I can fit an exponential function to a cosine function in the domain of $\;-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the least squares sense.

```
FindFit[Cos[x], {A*Exp[l*(Cos[x] - 1)], -π/2 <= x <= π/2}, {A, l},  x]
```

> ```
> FindFit::fitd: First argument Cos[x] in FindFit is not a list or a rectangular array.
> ```

I could create a table for `Cos[x]` to pass as the first parameter but I feel like I'm approaching this wrong and should be able to give *Mathematica* my problem in symbolic form. Perhaps, I should try Minimize but I didn't get any results out of it.

```
Minimize[{(Cos[x] - A*Exp[l*(Cos[x] - 1)])^2, -π/2 <= x <= π/2}, {A, l, x}]
```

> ```
> Minimize[{(-A E^(l (-1 + Cos[x])) + Cos[x])^2, -π/2 <= x <= π/2}, {A, l, x}]
> ```

Comment: @OleksandrR. Oh, right silly mistake, of course I need to minimize the sum of the squares. Just curious why can't it find an exact closed form solution?

Comment: Have a look at the solution to the integral. It contains Bessel and Struve functions. That one cannot find exact closed form arguments for these functions to make the integral equal a particular value is not too surprising, IMO.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the integral symbolically, then minimize numerically:

```
distance = 
 Integrate[(A*Exp[l*(Cos[x] - 1)] - Cos[x])^2, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  Assumptions -> (A | l) \[Element] Reals]

{min, sol} = NMinimize[distance, {A, l}]

Plot[{A*Exp[l*(Cos[x] - 1)], Cos[x]} /. sol // Evaluate, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh cool thanks! I like the plot style as well - helps visualize the error.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the plot. You first do a replace via the symbol /. that replaces A and l with the sol variable. Then what does the // Evaluate do? Thanks!

Comment: @coderdave It works without `Evaluate`.  Take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/difference-in-plot-when-using-evaluate-vs-when-not-using-evaluate) to see why I used it.