# Fit Gaussian to hyperbolic functions

Tags: fitting

I'd like to fit a trap potential

```
V4Sym[x_, a_, L_, c1_]
```

to a combination of two (or possibly more, but for now two) Gaussians:

```
doubleGauss[x_, in1_, in2_, x1_, x2_, σ1_, σ2_] := 
  in1 * Exp[-(x - x1)^2/σ1^2] + in2*Exp[-(x - x2)^2/σ2^2]
```

After a quick search, I came acrosss [this solution, which looked promising](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38066/fitting-one-function-to-another). 
However, if I try this, I get the following:

```
L := 10^-5
Lε := (L - 10^-8*L)/2
a := 10^8
c1 := 1

doubleGauss[x_, in1_, in2_, x1_, x2_, σ1_, σ2_] := 
 in1*Exp[-(x - x1)^2/σ1^2] + in2*Exp[-(x - x2)^2/σ2^2]
V4Sym[x_, a_, L_, c1_]:=c1*(Coth[a*(L+x)/2]*Coth[a*(L - x)/2])^2 - 2*a^2*(Sech[a*(L+x)/2]^2 + Sech[a*(L - x)/2]^2)
distance := Integrate[(V4Sym[x, a, L, c1] - doubleGauss[x, in1, in2, x1,  x2, σ1, σ2])^2, 
  {x, -Lε,  Lε},   Assumptions -> (in1 | in2 | x1 | x2) ∈ Reals]

{min, sol} =  NMinimize[distance, {in1, in2, x1, x2, σ1, σ2}]
```

The output I then get is

> PolynomialGCD::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD.

a few quick remarks: L, a and c1 are a set of parameters for which I've chosen values in the range of what I'll need in the end. Lε is for the integration boundaries since the potential diverges at |x|=L/2.

Does anyone have some hints on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: forgot the definition of the potential.

EDIT2: sorry, made a mistake in defining the potential here (I had defined it implicitly in my .nb and did not want to include that step here since it did not seem relevant) the actual potential is

```
V4Sym[x_, a_, L_, c1_] := 
 c1*(Coth[a*(L/2 + x)]*Coth[a*(L/2 - x)])^2 - 
  2*a^2*(Sech[a*(L/2 + x)]^2 + Sech[a*(L/2 - x)]^2)
```

So, as a whole, to plot it, we have

```
L := 10^-5
L\[CurlyEpsilon] := (L - 10^-8*L)/2
a := 10^8
c1 := 1
V4Sym[x_, a_, L_, c1_] := 
 c1*(Coth[a*(L/2 + x)]*Coth[a*(L/2 - x)])^2 - 
  2*a^2*(Sech[a*(L/2 + x)]^2 + Sech[a*(L/2 - x)]^2)
Plot[V4Sym[x, a, L, c1], {x, -L\[CurlyEpsilon], L\[CurlyEpsilon]}]
```

I apologize, my potential seems to behave weirdly for this small parameter L (although I can't seem to make out why exactly). Let's for now stick with L=c1=1. This is what the shape of the potential looks like in this case:

```
V4Sym[x_, a_, L_, c1_] := 
 c1*(Coth[a*(L/2 + x)]*Coth[a*(L/2 - x)])^2 - 
  2*a^2*(Sech[a*(L/2 + x)]^2 + Sech[a*(L/2 - x)]^2)
Plot[{Evaluate[V4Sym[x, 1, 1, 1]], V4Sym[x, 5, 1, 1], 
  V4Sym[x, 10, 1, 1], V4Sym[x, 30, 1, 1]}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"a=1", "a=5", "a=10", "a=30"}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1500, 150}, PlotLabel -> "L=1, c1=1"]
```

[image: Shape of V4Sym for a=1 (blue), a=5 (orange), a=10 (green) and a=30 (red)]

For values of a higher than 30, the shape stays the same, it only gets more extreme.

Now, if I try to approximate this rather well-behaved (apart from the boundaries) potential with my combination of two Gaussians, I still run into some problems:

```
L = 1;
L\[CurlyEpsilon] = (L - 10^-7*L)/2;
a = 30;
c1 = 1;
doubledistance[in1_?NumberQ, in2_?NumberQ, x1_?NumberQ, 
  x2_?NumberQ, \[Sigma]1_?NumberQ, \[Sigma]2_?NumberQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(V4Sym[x] - 
     doubleGauss[x, in1, in2, x1, 
      x2, \[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2])^2, {x, -L\[CurlyEpsilon], 
   L\[CurlyEpsilon]}]
    {min, doublesol} =  NMinimize[
  doubledistance[in1, in2, x1, x2, \[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2], {in1, in2, 
   x1, x2, \[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2}]
```

yields the output

> During evaluation of In[266]:= NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand
>   (-0.281773 E^(-12.6195 x^2)-0.990791 E^(-8.36999 x^2)+V4Sym[x])^2 has
>   evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the
>   region with boundaries {{-(9999999/20000000),9999999/20000000}}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[266]:= NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand
>   (-0.281773 E^(-12.6195 x^2)-0.990791 E^(-8.36999 x^2)+V4Sym[x])^2 has
>   evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the
>   region with boundaries {{-(9999999/20000000),9999999/20000000}}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[266]:= NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand
>   (-0.281773 E^(-12.6195 x^2)-0.990791 E^(-8.36999 x^2)+V4Sym[x])^2 has
>   evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the
>   region with boundaries {{-(9999999/20000000),9999999/20000000}}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[266]:= General::stop: Further output of
>   NIntegrate::inumr will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[266]:= NMinimize::nnum: The function value
>   NIntegrate[(V4Sym[x]-doubleGauss[x,0.990791,0.281773,-0.345651,0.281501])^2,{x,-L[CurlyEpsilon],L[CurlyEpsilon]}]
>   is not a number at {in1,in2,x1,x2,[Sigma]1,[Sigma]2} =
>   {0.990791,0.281773,0.300512,0.930797,-0.345651,0.281501}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[266]:= NMinimize::nnum: The function value
>   NIntegrate[(V4Sym[x]-doubleGauss[x,0.990791,0.281773,-0.345651,0.281501])^2,{x,-L[CurlyEpsilon],L[CurlyEpsilon]}]
>   is not a number at {in1,in2,x1,x2,[Sigma]1,[Sigma]2} =
>   {0.990791,0.281773,0.300512,0.930797,-0.345651,0.281501}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[266]:= NMinimize::nnum: The function value
>   NIntegrate[(V4Sym[x]-doubleGauss[x,0.990791,0.281773,-0.345651,0.281501])^2,{x,-L[CurlyEpsilon],L[CurlyEpsilon]}]
>   is not a number at {in1,in2,x1,x2,[Sigma]1,[Sigma]2} =
>   {0.990791,0.281773,0.300512,0.930797,-0.345651,0.281501}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[266]:= General::stop: Further output of
>   NMinimize::nnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[266]:= Set::shape: Lists {min,doublesol} and
>   NMinimize[doubledistance[in1,in2,x1,x2,[Sigma]1,[Sigma]2],{in1,in2,x1,x2,[Sigma]1,[Sigma]2}]
>   are not the same shape. >>
>
> Out[266]= NMinimize[  doubledistance[in1, in2, x1, x2, [Sigma]1,
>   [Sigma]2], {in1, in2,    x1, x2, [Sigma]1, [Sigma]2}]

Comment: What is the definition of `V4Sym`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that:

V4Sym[x_, a_, L_, c1_]:=c1*(Coth[a*(L+x)/2]*Coth[a*(L - x)/2])^2 - 
 2*a^2*(Sech[a*(L+x)/2]^2 + Sech[a*(L - x)/2]^2)

Comment: Edit the question to include the definition.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, I've made several plots of `V4Sym` throughout and, apart from the boundaries at `|x|=L/2`, where it has singularities, it is well-behaved.

Comment: I would adivse you to try using sums rather than integrals here. There’s no point is calculating them for such a simple minimization.

Comment: I've tried a sum to, but the problem I ended up with at last stayed the same.

Comment: The example curves you show don't look like curves that could be well-approximated by a mixture of a few Gaussian curves.  For example, your curves are symmetric about zero.  To have that symmetry in the approximation with two Gaussians you'd have 
to restrict the parameters:  $x_1=-x_2$, $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$, and $in_1=in_2$.  `V4Sym` seems easy to calculate so maybe if you explained why you needed an approximation to `V4Sym`, more direct help would be possible.

Answer (score 4):

Make the constants using `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed`. Make `distance` an explicit function of its parameters, and only defined when they have numeric values. Use `NIntegrate` to avoid symbolic integrals that might get into trouble with exponents.

```
doubleGauss[x_, in1_, in2_, x1_, 
  x2_, \[Sigma]1_, \[Sigma]2_] := 
 in1*Exp[-(x - x1)^2/\[Sigma]1^2] + in2*Exp[-(x - x2)^2/\[Sigma]2^2]

L = 10^-5;
L\[CurlyEpsilon] = (L - 10^-8*L)/2;
a = 10^8;
c1 = 1;

V4Sym[x_] := 
 c1*(Coth[a*(L + x)/2]*Coth[a*(L - x)/2])^2 - 
  2*a^2*(Sech[a*(L + x)/2]^2 + Sech[a*(L - x)/2]^2)
distance[in1_?NumberQ, in2_?NumberQ, x1_?NumberQ, 
  x2_?NumberQ, \[Sigma]1_?NumberQ, \[Sigma]2_?NumberQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(V4Sym[x] - 
     doubleGauss[x, in1, in2, x1, 
      x2, \[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2])^2, {x, -L\[CurlyEpsilon], 
   L\[CurlyEpsilon]}]

In[9]:= {min, sol} = 
 NMinimize[
  distance[in1, in2, x1, x2, \[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2], {in1, in2, x1, 
   x2, \[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2}]

Out[9]= {1.05066267514*10^-13, {in1 -> 0.980323726315, 
  in2 -> 1.00030736963, x1 -> -1.67814472669, 
  x2 -> 0.0197762596417, \[Sigma]1 -> -0.397188653907, \[Sigma]2 -> 
   0.976862432515}}
```