# Fitting a numerical function with another function that depends on parameters

Tags: fitting, numerical-value

I'd like to fit a branch of the Lambert function :

```
-ProductLog[-1, x]
```

in the interval $[-0.35,0]$ with a function of the form $-a\log(-bx)+c+d x$ or $-a\log(-x)+c+d x$ or something like that. I saw that the functions

```
-Log[-x] + 1.5 + 3 x
-1.5*Log[-x]
```

were not so bad but I'd like to fit better...

The command $Fit$ is not good for that kind of fitting, and [Fitting one function to another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38066/fitting-one-function-to-another) doesn't look appropriate either.

How could I proceed plz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
int[a_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[( \[Minus]a Log[\[Minus]x] + c + d x -ProductLog[-1, x])^2, {x, -.35, 0}]
opt = NMinimize[int[a, c, d], {a, c, d}]
(*{0.000222356, {a -> -1.13033, c -> -1.27779, d -> -2.88088}}*)
```

check result

```
Plot[{ \[Minus]a Log[\[Minus]x] + c + d x,ProductLog[-1, x]} /. opt[[2]] // Evaluate, {x, -.35, 0}]
```

[image]