# Colouring of multiple data sets in DiscretePlot

Tags: plotting, color

I noticed the following strange behaviour:

Let us first define an array of functions

```
    g[k_] := {Sin[k], 2*Sin[k]}
    gg = g[k]
```

When I plot this array of functions with

```
    DiscretePlot[{Sin[k], 2 Sin[k]}, {k, 1, 50}]
```

each of the two sets of points have a different colour. But, both

```
    DiscretePlot[gg, {k, 1, 50}]
```

and

```
    DiscretePlot[g[k], {k, 1, 50}]
```

show the two sets of points in blue.

I am more interested in the second case, because should the array of functions be large, it is more comfortable to use the definitions like `g` and `gg` given above. But I want to preserve the different colours. How do I do that?

Comment: Use `DiscretePlot[Evaluate@gg, {k, 1, 50}]` and `DiscretePlot[Evaluate@g[k], {k, 1, 50}]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/484

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right my question is a duplicate - sorry for this - and `Evaluate` solves the problem.