# How to Plot with different styles different InterpolatingFunction

Tags: plotting

Im sorry for this question I'm new and it may be a stupid question, but I can't find nothing specific.

I have these differential equations and `NDSolve` give me `InterpolatingFunctions` rules for `{Ca[t], Cb[t], Cc[t]}`:

```
Solu = NDSolve[{Ca'[t] == -Ca[t], Cb'[t] == 2*Ca[t] - Cb[t], Cc'[t] == Cb[t], 
  Ca[0] == 1, Cb[0] == 0, Cc[0] == 0}, {Ca[t], Cb[t], Cc[t]}, {t, 0, 0.3}]
```

Then I `Plot` with this

```
Plot[{Ca[t], Cb[t], Cc[t]} /. Solu, {t, 0, 0.3}, PlotLegends -> {Ca[t], Cb[t], Cc[t]}]
```

But `Plot` take all the several functions, that are in a flatten list, as the same function; it shows me the legend just for `Ca[t]`. You see that because they have the same color.

Comment: @Öskå I'd go with this one (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/52), personally.

Comment: user272185 just to be clear, we are not saying that this is a bad question. In fact, most new users run across it at some point, so it is a very common question. All of the ones we've linked to have good variations on why this issue comes up and how to get around it.

Comment: @rcollyer Easy, im just frustrated because i didn't find these before, KeyWords tricked me.

Comment: @user272185 The search engine is quite bad :)

Comment: Mathematica is, initially, frustrating, and the search engine on this site does not help. I'd suggest you look at the [Pitfalls for new users](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/52) question. It has some wonderful advice.