# Why does the replace all (/.) evaluate differently in plot

Tags: plotting, replacement

I'm plotting this function:

```
Plot[(2 (l/2 π)^2 ((2 π f)/c)^2 /. {f -> (f 10^9), 
     l -> .01, c -> 3 10^8}), {f, 17.5, 26.5}]
```

but it does not plot correctly unless I do this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[(2 (l/2 π)^2 ((2 π f)/c)^2 /. {f -> (f 10^9), 
     l -> .01, c -> 3 10^8})], {f, 17.5, 26.5}]
```

Why is the replace all command being evaluated differently in the two cases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate)

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/12 . `Plot` is `HoldAll` and it will substitute the value of `f` before evaluating the replacement, unless you explicitly ask for it to be `Evaluate`d first.  See here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html

Comment: I am working on an answer that I feel has value.  I ask others not to close this at this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is strongly related to [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate) but the specific issue there has to do with styling of lines rather than evaluation itself.

In this case the question is why the curve scale ends up different.  For that you need to understand how `Plot` works.  It is akin to [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) over the plot variables.  Now consider:

```
Block[{f = 3},
 (2 (l/2 π)^2 ((2 π f)/c)^2 /. {f -> (f 10^9), l -> .01, c -> 3 10^8})
]

Block[{f = 3},
 Evaluate[(2 (l/2 π)^2 ((2 π f)/c)^2 /. {f -> (f 10^9), l -> .01, c -> 3 10^8})]
]
```

> ```
> 1.94818*10^-18
>
> 1.94818
> ```

Clearly the replacement rule is not having the same effect in both cases.  Critically [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) does not hold its arguments therefore standard evaluation order is followed which means that we get something like this:

```
Block[{f = 3},
 foo[2 (l/2 π)^2 ((2 π f)/c)^2, {f -> (f 10^9), l -> .01, c -> 3 10^8}]
]
```

> ```
> foo[(18 l^2 π^4)/c^2, {3 -> 3000000000, l -> 0.01, c -> 300000000}]
> ```

(`foo` stands in as an arbitrary head with standard evaluation.)  Note that the replacement rule is now `3 -> 3000000000` and that `3` does not appear in the left-hand side.  We would need `ReplaceAll` to also hold its arguments to prevent this; it can be simulated using [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
Block[{f = 3},
 Unevaluated[2 (l/2 π)^2 ((2 π f)/c)^2] /. 
  Unevaluated[{f -> (f 10^9), l -> .01, c -> 3 10^8}]
]
```

> ```
> 1.94818
> ```

[`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) works in your example because it causes a symbolic evaluation outside the scope of `Plot`.  However for the same reason if `f` has a global value it will again fail.  It is more robust to use `Unevaluated` as shown above but this is rather inconvenient.  There is another robust though undocumented method: the `Plot` option `Evaluated -> True`.  This causes an evaluation of the plot function before a value is substituted but *after* the variable is scoped by `Plot`:

```
f = 1.23;

Plot[(2 (l/2 π)^2 ((2 π f)/c)^2 /. {f -> (f 10^9), l -> .01, c -> 3 10^8}),
  {f, 17.5, 26.5}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

This option won't scope the other two replacement symbols `l` and `c` of course but it is still my preferred approach for such problems.  Also look at [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) which can be of some utility.