# Plot command uses same colors when applying pattern on list

Tags: plotting

When I do

```
Plot[{fun1,fun2} ./ val1->1,{t,0,10}]
```

then both plots are in the same color!
If I use instead

```
Plot[{fun1./ val1->1,fun2./ val1->1},{t,0,10}]
```

it uses different colors, as expected.
This is very annoying, particularly because often I supply a list already and need to perform last pattern substitutions...

If possible, the solution should not be supplying colors manually.
I would look either for a setting to disable this behavior or something like "hold all" in MATLAB which automatically picks colors without manually supplying it.

Comment: This question is answered here: [(1731)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121)
[(64909)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64909/121)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap substitution by Evaluate[]:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Sin[val1 x], Cos[val1 x]} /. val1 -> 1], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: I recommend using `Evaluated -> True` instead.  Please see: [(7561)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7561/121), [(7832)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121)