# Plot Legends when first argument was generated by Table[]

Tags: plotting, legending

I can get a plot to generate legends for different functions when these functions are put into a hand-coded list. However, when I generate the list of functions using Table[] only one legend is generated. In the code below four plots are generated but only the first two have different legends and colors for the two curves plotted.

Is there a way to produce one legend per curve plotted when the list of functions is generated by Table (or some other function)?

```
f1[x_] := Sin[x];
f2[x_] := Cos[x];
f = {f1, f2}
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> {"Sin", "Cos"}]
Plot[{f[[1]][x], f[[2]][x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotLegends -> {"Sin", "Cos"}]
Plot[Table[f[[i]][x], {i, 1, 2}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotLegends -> {"Sin", "Cos"}]
Plot[Table[f[[i]][x], {i, 1, 2}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"]
```

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to include an `Evaluate`:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[[i]][x], {i, 1, 2}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"]
```

which produces the correct result:

[image]

In general, if you are trying to `Plot` a `Table` in one step, you should always `Evaluate` the `Table` first, ie, `Plot[Evaluate@Table[...], ...]`.

**Brief explanation of behavior**: By adding an `Evaluate`, you force symbolic evaluation of the `Table` first, and then `Plot` operates on the resulting table of two expressions, and then `PlotLegends` operates on the expressions, producing the correct pair of curves and labels.

In contrast, without the `Evaluate`, `Plot` sequentially evaluates `Table[...]` at the particular floating-point value currently being plotted, creating a sequence of lists of floating point numbers, which are then interpreted (I guess?) as a single function, thus causing both curves to be the same blue color. I have no idea what `PlotLegends` does, but I imagine it's similarly incorrect.

Comment: PlotLegends operates on a distinguishability criteria, the lines have to be visually distinct to be given a legend.