# The use of Evaluate in NDSolve and Plotting the answer

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am having a bit of hard time understanding the use of Evaluate when plotting the output of NDSolve. From the documentation, I enter:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[x]^2 - y[x]^2 == 0, y[0]^2 == 4}, y[x], {x, 1}]
```

Then I can plot without the use of Evaluate:

```
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Which give this image:

[image]

Yet, when I add Evaluate (which seems to be the preference in the tutorials (currently reading tutorial/NumericalSolutionOfDifferentialEquations), but not explained in that particular tutorial, I get the following result:

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

How come this one is colored differently?

Comment: Please see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate